# Error "ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application"

Tags: python, opencv, importerror

I have this issue where I try to import `cv2` on Python and get the following error message.

```
>>> import cv2
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

I do understand there are many posts about this where it is suggested that the bitness of the package is different from the Python package.

However, everything I am running is 64 bits.  I am on Windows 7 64 bits, I have the [winpython](http://code.google.com/p/winpython/downloads/detail?name=WinPython-64bit-2.7.3.3.exe) 2.7.3.3, 64 bits distribution, and I compiled OpenCV in 64 bits with the instruction provided [here](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/windows_install/windows_install.html) and placed the cv2.pyd DLL file in the Lib/site-packages folder of the Python interpreter.

Unfortunately, the suggestion of using the 32 bits version of Python isn't working for me any more as I have to handle NumPy arrays too large for 32 bits.

---

The only thing missing was to add the new NumPy binaries path (C:\opencv\build\bin\Release) to the Windows PATH environment variable, restart the Python interpreter.

Everything seems to be working fine now!

Comment: The link is (effectively) broken: *"401: Anonymous caller does not have storage.objects.get access to the Google Cloud Storage object."*

Comment: More details on the error: [\[SO\]: Python Ctypes - loading dll throws OSError: \[WinError 193\] %1 is not a valid Win32 application (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57297745/4788546).

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The ImportError message is a bit misleading because of the reference to Win32, whereas the problem was simply the OpenCV DLLs were not found.

This problem was solved by adding the path the OpenCV binaries to the Windows PATH environment variable (as an example, on my computer this path is: *C:\opencv\build\bin\Release*).

Comment: What is the steps taken to do this?

Comment: What I don't get is, why doesn't the error message state the DLL that couldn't be loaded? %1 merely seems to be a placeholder for the name of the DLL.

Comment: Ah ok. So you have to copy the cv2.pyd from the x64 folder, if you're on 64-bit machine to fix that error. @antred It is a placeholder. It normally gets replaced with the DLL but it doesn't work because the 32 bit fails to load on a 64 bit machine.

Comment: @Francis: You, sir, deserve a medal! Thanks, really.

Comment: @AlexW You're saying cv2.pyd should be copied... but where to copy it?

Comment: @Belial I'm not on the machine that I installed OpenCV on right now, but I believe you have to copy that file from the 64-bit folder in `C:\opencv\build\bin\Release` into the 32-bit folder.

Comment: There might have 32bit `.dll` files as well in your machine. Make sure to delete them if you have no use with them.

Answer (score 5):

You could try installing the 32 bit version of OpenCV.

Comment: Please mind that this issue is already solved as mentionned in the UPDATE section of the question.

Comment: @Francis once you have found a solution, please always add it as an Answer, instead of adding it to your Question.

Answer (score 3):

Or you have to rebuild the cv2 module for Windows 64 bit.

Answer (score 3):

I just hit this and the problem was that the package had at one point been installed in the per-user packages directory. (On Windows.) aka %AppData%\Python. So Python was looking there first, finding an old 32-bit version of the .pyd file, and failing with the listed error. Unfortunately pip uninstall  by itself wasn't enough to clean this, and at this time pip 10.0.1 doesn't seem to have a --user parameter for uninstall, only for install.

tl;dr Deleting the old .pyd from %AppData%\python\python27\site-packages resolved this problem for me.

Comment: This was my problem as well. There was an older version of python that didn't seem to be deleted properly. Had to run the System File Checker to clean it up

Answer (score 2):

This error can also appear when Python versions are mixed:

For example, if any of the DLL file to be loaded has been compiled using Python 2.7.16 and you try to import with Python 2.7.15 the error `ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.` is thrown.

This is at least what I've found to be the problem in my case.

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is copy the *cv2.pyd* file from the x86 folder (**C:\opencv\build\python\2.7\x86\** for example) to **C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\**, not from the x64 folder.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error as the one mentioned in previous answers, but it happens only when I use `pyinstaller`.

I did the following in my [Poetry](https://python-poetry.org/) [venv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html):

`poetry run python -m pip install pypiwin32`

And it worked for me. I am using

```
python                            3.8.10
pyinstaller                       4.7
# Those are the versions that worked for me
pypiwin32                         223
pywin32                           303
pywin32-ctypes                    0.2.0
```

Answer (score 0):

When I had this error, it went away after I my computer crashed and restarted. Try closing and reopening your IDE. If that doesn't work, try restarting your computer. I had just installed the libraries at that point without restarting [PyCharm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PyCharm) when I got this error.

I never closed PyCharm first to test, because my blasted computer keeps crashing randomly... I am working on that one, but it at least it solved this problem... little victories... :).