# ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application. But the DLL's are there

Tags: python, opencv, dll, path

I have a situation very much like the one at *[Error "ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14629818/importerror-dll-load-failed-1-is-not-a-valid-win32-application)*, but the answer there isn't working for me.

My Python code says:

```
import cv2
```

But that line throws the error shown in the title of this question.

I have OpenCV installed in `C:\lib\opencv` on this 64-bit machine. I'm using 64-bit Python.

My PYTHONPATH variable: `PYTHONPATH=C:\lib\opencv\build\python\2.7`. This folder contains `cv2.pyd` and that's all.

My PATH variable: `Path=%OPENCV_DIR%\bin;...` This folder contains 39 DLL files such as `opencv_core246d.dll`.

OPENCV_DIR has this value: `OPENCV_DIR=C:\lib\opencv\build\x64\vc11`.

The solution at *[Error "ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14629818/importerror-dll-load-failed-1-is-not-a-valid-win32-application)* says to add "the new opencv binaries path (`C:\opencv\build\bin\Release`) to the Windows PATH environment variable". But as shown above, I already have the OpenCV binaries folder (`C:\lib\opencv\build\x64\vc11\bin`) in my PATH. And my OpenCV installation doesn't have any Release folders (except for an empty one under *build/java*).

What's going wrong? Can I tell Python to verbosely trace the loading process? Exactly what DLL files is it looking for?

I noticed that, according to http://www.dependencywalker.com/, the `cv2.pyd` in `C:\lib\opencv\build\python\2.7` is 32-bit, whereas the machine and the Python I'm running are 64-bit. Could that be the problem? And if so, where can I find a 64-bit version of cv2.pyd?

Comment: click [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#opencv)    and find the 64-bit opencv

Comment: @KillConsole: thanks, I'll try it. Since the install package I downloaded had both x86 and x64 subfolders, I assumed it included everything there was to have for 64-bit. Apparently not. Hooray, that fixed it! Now we're on to "ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import", so I'll try the same site for 64-bit numpy. If you make your comment into an answer, I'll upvote and accept it.

Comment: which Python version did you use ? (not in terms of processor bits version)

Comment: @Begueradj: 2.7, if that's what you're asking.

Comment: Hi all, I encountered the same issue (after copying `x64/cv2.pyd`, because my PC is 64-bit) , however then I tried copying `x86/cv2.pyd` and it worked. Is this because my Python installation 32-bit (I'm not sure it is but it's the only way I can make sense of this) ?

Comment: For me it happened with pycrypto, and all I had to do is to reinstall it. Problem solved.

Comment: I had the same problem and none of the below solutions helped me, so it turned out that my `PYTHONPATH` used to contain the entries which the install of SimpleCV library has left there.  Despite I have already uninstalled the SimpleCV, the `PYTHONPATH` was not restored and was pointing to some directories with conflicting versions of OpenCV left by SimpleCV install.  Solution: clear the `PYTHONPATH`.

Comment: More details on the error: [\[SO\]: Python Ctypes - loading dll throws OSError: \[WinError 193\] %1 is not a valid Win32 application (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57297745/4788546).

Answer (score 88, accepted):

[Unofficial Windows Binaries for Python Extension Packages](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/)

You can find any Python libraries from here.

Comment: this really helped. I am not sure what was wrong. I had a version of opencv, anaconda3, python3. Installed opencv_python-3.3.0+contrib-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64 from above package list and was able to import cv2 successfully after hours of struggle. Thanks a ton.

Comment: This link seem dead.

Answer (score 45):

Please check if the Python version you are using is also 64 bit. If not then that could be the issue. You would be using a 32-bit Python version and would have installed a 64 bit binaries for the OpenCV library.

Comment: As mentioned in the question, I was using 64-bit Python.

Answer (score 20):

Wow, I found yet another case for this problem. None of the above worked. Eventually I used python's ability to introspect what was being loaded. For Python 2.7, this means:

```
import imp
imp.find_module("cv2")
```

This turned up a completely unexpected "cv2.pyd" file in an [Anaconda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anaconda_(Python_distribution)) DLL directory that wasn't touched by multiple uninstall/install attempts. Python was looking there first and not finding my good installation. I deleted that cv2.pyd file and tried imp.find_module("cv2") again and python immediately found the right file and cv2 started working.

So if none of the other solutions work for you, make sure you use Python introspection to see what file Python is trying to load.

Comment: I had an issue were it was trying to run a version of the file in a different folder completely. This solution here helped me figure out what was really going on. Thanks!

Comment: This is an excellent answer, thanks! I ran into an issue with PyDev where it was loading "ctypes" from an incompatible installation of python, and I realized that I needed to set up my interpreter to use WinPython, which fixed it.

Answer (score 7):

In my case, I have 64-bit Python, and it was *lxml* that was the wrong version--I should have been using the x64 version of that as well. I solved this by downloading the 64-bit version of lxml here:

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/lxml/3.4.1

```
lxml-3.4.1.win-amd64-py2.7.exe
```

This was the simplest answer to a frustrating issue.

Answer (score 6):

I just had this problem. It turns out it was just because I was using an 64-bit version of the OpenCV file. I tried the x86 and it worked.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. Here's what I did:

1. I downloaded the pywin32 wheel file from [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pypiwin32/219), then
2. I uninstalled the **pywin32** module. To uninstall, execute the following command in a command prompt.

   `pip uninstall pywin32`
3. Then, I reinstalled **pywin32**. To install it, open the command prompt in the same directory where the pywin32 wheel file lies. Then execute the following command.

   `pip install <Name of the wheel file with extension>`
   Wheel file will be like: **piwin32-XXX-cpXX-none-win32.whl**

It solves the problem for me.

Answer (score 2):

I copied `cv2.pyd` file from `/opencv/build/python/2.7/x86` folder instead of from `/x64` folder to `C:/Python27/Lib/site-packeges`. I followed rest of the instructions provided [here](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_setup/py_setup_in_windows/py_setup_in_windows.html#install-opencv-python-in-windows).

Added by someone else, not verified: I also copy file `cv2.pyd` to folder `C:/Python27/Lib/site-packages/cv2`. It works.

Answer (score 2):

For me the problem was that I was using different versions of Python in the *same* Eclipse project. My setup was not consistent with the *Project Properties* and the *Run Configuration* Python versions.

In menu *Project* → *Properties* → *PyDev*, I had the *Interpreter* set to Python 2.7.11.

In *Run Configurations* → *Interpreter*, I was using the *Default Interpreter*. Changing it to Python 2.7.11 fixed the problem.

Answer (score 2):

If your build system ([CMake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CMake) in my case) copies the file from `<name>.dll` to `<name>.pyd`, you will get this error if the original file wasn't actually a DLL file. In my case, building shared libraries got switched off, so the underlying file was actually a `*.lib`.

I discovered this error by loading the `pyd` file in [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) and finding that it wasn't valid.

Answer (score 2):

Update NumPy.

`pip install numpy --upgrade`

It works for me!

Answer (score 2):

This one worked for me:

```
pip install -- pywin32==227
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Why it worked for you? Please, could you add more details to this answer?

Comment: Thank you! This actually worked for me. I found that I was using pywin 228, and downgrading to 227 made everything work again. Obviously something must have been added to 228 that broke backwards compatibility, but I have no idea of what.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue when I uninstalled and reinstalled a different version of 2.7.x of Python on my system using a 32-bit Windows Installer. I got the same error on most of my import statements.

I uninstalled the newly installed Python, downloaded a 64-bit Windows installer, reinstalled Python again, and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

So I had problems installing vtk under Windows (as I use Python 3.7, there isn't any binary available so far. Just for older Python versions `pip install vtk` is not working)

I did wrote Python in my cmd:

`Python 3.7.3 on win32`

So I now know I have Python 3.7.3 running on a 32 bit.

I then downloaded the correct wheel at [VTK‑8.2.0‑cp37‑cp37m‑win32.whl](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/)

Next I installed that wheel:

```
pip install VTK-8.2.0-cp37-cp37m-win32.whl
```

Then I tested it and it worked:

```
python
import vtk
```

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same problem while trying to write code concerning speech-to-text.

The solution was very simple. Uninstall the previous pywin32 using the pip method:

```
pip uninstall pywin32
```

The above will remove the existing one which is by default for 32 bit computers. And install it again using

```
pip install pywin32
```

This will install the one for the 64 bit computer which you are using.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue while trying to run uvicorn,
Creating a new virtual environment and reinstalling the python packages worked

Answer (score 0):

First I copied `cv2.pyd` from `/opencv/build/python/2.7/x86` to `C:/Python27/Lib/site-packeges`. The error was

> "RuntimeError: module compiled against API version 9 but this version of numpy is 7"

Then I installed `numpy-1.8.0-win32-superpack-python2.7.exe` and OpenCV works fine.

```
>>> import cv2
>>> print cv2.__version__
2.4.13
```

Answer (score 0):

You can install `opencv` from [official](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/opencv-python) or [unofficial](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#opencv) sites.

Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41849353/python-3-5-opencv-3-2-windows-7-64-bits-anaconda-3-importerror-dll-load-fa) question and [this](https://github.com/skvark/opencv-python/issues/36) issue if you are using `Anaconda`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Please make sure that you have installed a Python 2.7.12 or below version. Otherwise you will definitely get this error.
2. Make sure the Oracle client is 64 bit installed if the OS is 64 bit.
3. Make sure the Microsoft Visual C++ compiler for Python 2.7 is 64 for bit for a 64 bit OS or 32 bit for 32 bit.

Note: *If* your OS is 64 bit, install all packages of 64 bit or if the OS is 32 bit, install the 32-bit package.

Answer (score 0):

It has a very simple solution.
After installing `opencv`
place

`cv2.pyd` from `C:\opencv\build\python\2.7\ **x64**` to `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages`

instead of, place `cv2.pyd` from `C:\opencv\build\python\2.7\ **x86**` to `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages`

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when trying to import MySQLdb.

What worked for me was to uninstall Python and then reinstall it.

I got the error after installing npm (https://www.npmjs.com/get-npm). One thing it did was install Python even though I already had it.

Answer (score 0):

This has worked for me. I have tried different methods, but this was my best solution.

Open a command prompt and type the following;

```
pip install opencv-python
```

(Make sure your Internet connection is on.)

After that, try importing it again.

Answer (score 0):

It could also be that your [Anaconda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anaconda_(Python_distribution)) version is 32 bit when it should be 64 bit.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **pycharm** I go to settings -> python interpretation and click the + button and search for the name on the list of python packages there
[An image showing where to go when you want to install something](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pma1G.png)

Answer (score -2):

I found the solution. Maybe you can try to use the cmd window rather than the [Anaconda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anaconda_(Python_distribution)) prompt window to start your first [Scrapy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrapy) test.