# ImportError when trying to import package pyRserve

Tags: python, python-2.7, importerror, rserve, pyrserve

I did an easy_install onto Windows 7 of the pyRserve package but when I run `import pyRserve` I get the following Import Error.

I'm using Python 2.7.5.

Any suggestions?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<module1>", line 2, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyrserve-0.7.3-py2.7.egg\pyRserve\__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    from .rconn import connect
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyrserve-0.7.3-py2.7.egg\pyRserve\rconn.py", line 7, in <module>
    from . import rtypes
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyrserve-0.7.3-py2.7.egg\pyRserve\rtypes.py", line 4, in <module>
    import numpy
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 137, in <module>
    import add_newdocs
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\add_newdocs.py", line 9, in <module>
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from type_check import *
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\type_check.py", line 8, in <module>
    import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    import multiarray
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

Comment: Please refer the http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19019720/importerror-dll-load-failed-1-is-not-a-valid-win32-application-but-the-dlls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using 64 bit Python and when I switched to 32 bit it worked fine.

I'm guessing the package in only configured to work with 32 bit...