# How to download PYODBC on Python 3.4

Tags: python, python-3.4, pyodbc, pypyodbc

I've been trying to download PYODBC 1.3 onto Python 3.4 for about 2 weeks.

I've gone to: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pypyodbc/1.3.0 to download the folders.

When I run the easy_install.py and pyodbc.py, it seems to run fine. But then when I try to create a new query or whatever, and when I import PYODBC, it says "No module named 'pyodbc'.

Can I please get step by step instructions to download it?

I have Windows 32 bit, if that helps.

Any information would help me tremendously! Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pyodbc and python 3.4 on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23299034/pyodbc-and-python-3-4-on-windows)

Answer (score -1):

[pypyodbc](https://pypi.org/project/pypyodbc) and [pyodbc](https://pypi.org/project/pyodbc/) are different modules. Decide which one you want (they're very similar, though I've seen some have an easier time with Unicode data using pypyodbc) and

```
import pypyodbc
```

or

```
import pyodbc
```

Unless you specifically need version `1.3.0` of pypyodbc, go grab the [latest](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pypyodbc).

Comment: I'm trying to get pyodbc. and I actually have 1.3.3. When I try to import it, I receive this message and I don't know why: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python34/test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pyodbc
ImportError: No module named 'pyodbc'

Comment: There is no available 1.3.3 version of `pyodbc`, but 1.3.3 is available for **`pypyodbc`**.

Comment: Oh wow, I didn't even realize that was a pypyodbc website. How can I download pyodbc?

Comment: Check the pyodbc link in this answer.

Comment: In the downloads section, there isn't a download for Python 3.4?

Comment: Thank you very much Bryan!! You have no idea how much help you've been.