# Error "filename.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform"

Tags: python, pip

I would like to install `scipy-0.15.1-cp33-none-win_amd64.whl` that I have saved to the local drive. I am using:

```
pip 6.0.8 from C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages
python 2.7.9 (default, Dec 10 2014, 12:28:03) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]
```

When I run:

```
pip install scipy-0.15.1-cp33-none-win_amd64.whl
```

I get the following error:

> scipy-0.15.1-cp33-none-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform

What is the problem?

Answer (score 547, accepted):

`cp33` means `CPython 3.3`.

You need `scipy‑0.15.1‑cp27‑none‑win_amd64.whl` instead.

Comment: I had this issue too (with numpy though) so I downloaded all of the `cp27` [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy) and tried each one until one worked perfectly (in my case `numpy-1.9.3+vanilla-cp27-none-win32`)

Comment: had same issue for opencv, I have python 3.5. So download cp35 and pip install filename.whl

Comment: start Python and run: `import platform` and then `platform.architecture()` to see which version of Python you're running so you know which .whl to download!

Comment: Thanks @gregorio099. I'm running a 64-bit version of Windows, but apparently a 32-bit version of Python. Your comment saved me some time.

Comment: Also, if you have multiple versions of python installed, you may also get this error.   In my case, I wanted to install scipy into the 2.7 version, so on the cmd line, I explicitly called the version of python I wanted up upgrade (and install the wheel file for).  For example:   `C:\Python27amd67\python -m pip install scipy-1.0.b1-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl`.

Comment: @gregorio099 had same issue. I have `python 3.7` and `arch: ('64bit', 'ELF')`. I am getting error: `ERROR: scipy-1.4.1-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform`. I am using docker to run this

Comment: hello . all version for `cpython` in this [link](https://pypi.org/project/cPython/#history).not version `3.3`

Comment: I don't understand why this got so many upvotes. It may have solved the OP's problem, but it does nothing to help the general reader who encounters a "filename.whl is not supported wheel on this platform" error.

Comment: @Accumulation it solved my problem.  I was trying to install gdal, and took the 312 to be Python 3, Visual C 12 or such.  And so I banged my head for far too long, trying too many silly things, before reading this answer to finally take a closer look at the naming conventions.

Answer (score 283):

This can also be caused by using an out-of-date `pip` with a recent wheel file.

I was very confused, because I was installing `numpy-1.10.4+mkl-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl` (from [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/)), and it is definitely the correct version for my Python installation (Windows 64-bit Python 2.7.11). I got the "not supported wheel on this platform" error.

Upgrading pip with `python -m pip install --upgrade pip` solved it.

Comment: Thank you! I was getting this message after installing Python 3.4 from the MSI installer.  Turned out the installer included PIP 1.5.6, which was generating the "not supported" message. After upgrading, I ended up with PIP 8.1.1, which solved the problem.

Comment: Yeah, the default with a fresh Python installation seems to usually be old. Same with a new virtualenv, which installs its own pip.

Comment: Upgrading to pip 9.0.1 from a previous version(8.1.1 for Py3 and 7.0.1 for Py2) solved the issue for me

Comment: On windows the command should be py -m pip install --upgrade pip

Comment: @Freeze It might depend on the version and installation. On my Windows machine, `python` is Python 2.7 and `py` is 3.5.

Comment: I was trying to install a `*-cp34-cp34m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl` package on Debian 8 with the `python3`, `python3-pip` (1.5.6) packages from the jessie repositories.  It turns out that `manylinux1` support wasn't [added to pip until 8.1.0](https://github.com/pypa/pip/pull/3497).

Comment: I had this issue as well. Indeed upgrading pip to the latest version corrected the issue.

Comment: Using pip3 instead of pip could also solve it on Ubuntu

Comment: Helpful! For example, manylinux2014 requires pip >= 19.3, manylinux2010 requires pip >=19.0

Answer (score 109):

I had the same problem while installing scipy-0.17.0-cp35-none-win_amd64.whl and my Python version was 3.5. It returned the same error message:

```
scipy-0.17.0-cp35-none-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

I realized that amd64 is not about my Windows, but about the Python version. Actually I am using a 32-bit Python on a 64-bit Windows. Installing the following file solved the issue:

```
scipy-0.17.0-cp35-none-win32.whl
```

Comment: I think I am having the same issue. how did you check that your python was 32bit?

Comment: @user1757654, please check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1405913/how-do-i-determine-if-my-python-shell-is-executing-in-32bit-or-64bit-mode-on-os

Comment: Thank you very much for this valuable information. amd64 is indeed not about the windows version but the python's.

Answer (score 35):

Change the filename to `scipy-0.15.1-cp33-none-any.whl` and then run this command:

```
pip install scipy-0.15.1-cp33-none-any.whl
```

It should work :-)

Comment: Just a workaround, or do you have any supporting reason?

Comment: This worked for me, but you should note that you are just lying to `pip` by doing this and this may broke.

Comment: Yes,this works for me.I use `python -m pip debug --verbose` to detect which wheel my pip support,in the return list `cp39-none-any` mentioned.I guess `-none-any` not means `*`,that means anything.Also I meet this problem in my virtual env's pip.Do hope my reply can help someone.

Answer (score 30):

I come across this problem because of a wrong name of my package (`scipy-0.17.0-cp27-none-win_amd64 (1)`).

After I deleted the '(1)' and changed the package to
`scipy-0.17.0-cp27-none-win_amd64`, the problem got resolved.

Comment: Thanks so much! I couldn't believe my eyes that pip judges which platform the wheel pertains to by name!

Comment: You saved my day, I can't believe pip depends on name of file

Comment: I had this issue as well, with a numpy wheel - I had replaced a + with a - when I uploaded it to our nexus repository.  Changing the name back before pip install fixed it - Thanks!

Answer (score 19):

If you are totally new to Python, read step by step or go directly to 5th step directly.

Follow the below method to install [SciPy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SciPy) 0.18.1 on Windows 64-bit, Python 64-bit.

**Be careful with the versions of**

1. Python
2. Windows
3. .whl version of [NumPy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NumPy) and SciPy files
4. **First install NumPy and then SciPy.**

   ```
    pip install FileName.whl
   ```
5. For NumPy: [http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy)
   For SciPy: [http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#scipy](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#scipy)

Be aware of the file name (what I mean is check the "cp" number).
Example: *scipy-0.18.1-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl*

To check which "cp" number is supported by your pip. Go to point number 2 below.

If you are using .whl file, the following errors are likely to occur.

> 1. You are using pip version 7.1.0, however version 8.1.2 is available.

You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command

> 2. scipy-0.15.1-cp33-none-win_amd64.whl.whl is not supported wheel on this platform

For the above error: start Python (in my case 3.5), and type:

`import pip print(pip.pep425tags.get_supported())`

Output:

> [('cp35', 'cp35m', 'win_amd64'), ('cp35', 'none', 'win_amd64'), ('py3', 'none', 'win_amd64'), ('cp35', 'none', 'any'), ('cp3', 'none', 'any'), ('py35', 'none', 'any'), ('py3', 'none', 'any'), ('py34', 'none', 'any'), ('py33', 'none', 'any'), ('py32', 'none', 'any'), ('py31', 'none', 'any'), ('py30', 'none', 'any')]

In the output you will observe "cp35" is there, so download "cp35" for NumPy as well as SciPy.

Comment: Apparently, on some platforms, you need `import pip._internal` followed by 
`print(pip._internal.pep425tags.get_supported())`

Comment: Neither `pip.pep425tags.get_supported()` nor `pip._internal.pep425tags.get_supported()` is recognized on my system (Windows 10, pip version 20.0.2)

Answer (score 13):

Please do notice that all platform requirements **are taken from the name of the *.whl** file!

So be very careful with **renaming** of *.whl package. I occasionally renamed my newly compiled [TensorFlow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TensorFlow) package from

```
tensorflow-1.11.0-cp36-cp36m-linux_x86_64.whl
```

to

```
tensorflow-1.11.0-cp36-cp36m-linux_x86_64_gpu.whl
```

just to remind myself about [GPU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphics_processing_unit) support and struggled with

> tensorflow-1.11.0-cp36-cp36m-linux_x86_64_gpu.whl is not a supported
> wheel on this platform.

error for about half an hour.

Comment: This actually saved my life !! Thanks a ton !! With this same package actually :)

Answer (score 11):

First of all, **cp33** means that it is to be used when you have **Python 3.3** running on your system. So if you have **Python 2.7** on your system, try installing the **cp27** version.

Installing **scipy-0.18.1-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl**, needs a Python 2.7 running and a 64-bit system.

If you are still getting an error saying "scipy-0.18.1-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform", then go for the win32 version.
By this I mean install **scipy-0.18.1-cp27-cp27m-win32.whl** instead of the first one.
This is because you might be running a 32-bit python on a 64-bit system.
The last step successfully installed scipy for me.

Comment: "cp" for "[CPython](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPython)"?

Answer (score 9):

*cpXX* indicates the Python version.

Whichever Python X.X version you have installed into your system, download that particular *cpxx* file.

For example, if you have installed Python version 3.7 then
install
packagename-packageversion-cp37-cp37m-osx_10_13_x86_64.whl

Answer (score 6):

Things to check:

1. You are downloading proper version like cp27 (means for Python 2.7) cp36 (means for Python 3.6).
2. Check of which architecture (32 bit or 64 bit) your Python is (you can do it so by opening Python [IDLE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IDLE) and typing).

   ```
    import platform
    platform.architecture()
   ```

   Now download the file of that bit, irrespective of your system architecture.
3. Check whether you're using the correct filename (i.e., it should not be appended with (1) which might happen if you download the file twice)
4. Check if your pip is updated or not. If not, you can use:

   `python -m pip install -upgrade pip`

Comment: On step 2 you can rather ask pip for "compatible tags" instead, using `python -m pip debug --verbose`, which will list the filename suffixes it's happy to accept.

Answer (score 4):

For my case, with a dlib installation into my Python installation (Python 3.6.9), I have found that changing the [WHL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuptools#Package_format) file name from **dlib-19.8.1-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl** to **dlib-19.8.1-cp36-none-any.whl** works for me.

Here is the way I run pip install to install dlib:

```
pip3 install dlib-19.8.1-cp36-none-any.whl
```

However, I still wonder whether there are any alternatives to installation of a WHL file by the pip command without changing the name.

Answer (score 3):

I tried to install *scikit-image*, but I got the following error when I tried to install the .whl file, even though my installed version of Python was 2.7 32-bit:

> scikit_image-0.12.3-cp27-cp27m-win32.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

However, I also got this message before the error message:

> You are using pip version 7.1.0, however version 8.1.2 is available. 
> You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.

I then ran the command `python -m pip install --upgrade pip` and then `pip install scikit_image-0.12.3-cp27-cp27m-win32.whl` worked fine.

Answer (score 3):

I'm deploying [Flask](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flask_%28web_framework%29) using Python 3.4 on [IIS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Information_Services).

The following steps worked for me:

1. Upgrade pip
2. Install the wheel file for [NumPy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NumPy)
3. `pip install pandas`

Answer (score 3):

It's better to check the version of Python where you want to install your package.

If the [wheel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuptools#Package_format) was built for Python 3 and your Python version is Python 2.x you may get this error.

While installing using pip, follow this convention:

```
python2 -m pip install XXXXXX.whl # If the .whl file is for Python 2
python3 -m pip install XXXXXX.whl # If the .whl file is for Python 3
```

Comment: I run the code '!python -m pip install Twisted-17.9.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl' but I get this error: 'Requirement 'Twisted-17.9.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl' looks like a filename, but the file does not exist
Twisted-17.9.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.'

Comment: I'm using windows 10 and python 3.8. Every answers not worked for me but only this answer worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem, installing a 64-bit version for Python 2.7 on Windows 7 64-bit. Everything was up-to-date, yet I got the message:

`scipy-0.18.1-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl is not supported wheel on this platform`

Then I downloaded a 32-bit [.whl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuptools#Package_format) file and it worked.

```
pip install scipy-0.18.1-cp27-cp27m-win32.whl
```

I suspect that the problem was probably that I didn’t have an [AMD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Micro_Devices) processor, rather an Intel one, and the [SciPy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SciPy) 64-bit version says amd64 at the end.

Answer (score 1):

This error might happen because of the difference between armv7 and armv6. If you download the package for armv7 and try to install for armv6, this error occurs.

Comment: On what kind of system? [Raspberry Pi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raspberry_Pi)? [Android](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_%28operating_system%29)? [M1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_M1)? Something else?

Comment: Yes on Raspberry Pi, if we download packages for CM4 to SD card, and try to run that SD card on Pi Zero it does not work. If we download package for Pi Zero and try to work with CM4 it works.

Answer (score 1):

For me I had similar issue. In my case, I didn't notice the python version was different (32bit vs 64bit) between the computers.

By the way, you can still do it, but you will need to manually replace all the whls files that are not recognized.

for example, for `cryptography-36.0.1`, from
https://pypi.org/project/cryptography/36.0.1/#files
use:

`cryptography-36.0.1-cp36-abi3-win32.whl` (32bit)
vs
`cryptography-36.0.1-cp36-abi3-win_amd64.whl` (64bit)

In addition, for some reason there were version differences between what was in the requirements.txt file, versus the whl files version in the folder.
For example, I had numpy `1.22.3` in requirements file, and `numpy-1.22.2-cp39-cp39-win32.whl` in the folder.

So make sure they match, and adjust the requirements file accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Try [Conda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conda_(package_manager)) for installation. It seems to resolve versions
on the fly:

`conda install scikit-learn`

Answer (score 0):

Simply, if you have more than one Python installation on your system, for example, **2.7/3.4/3.5**, it's necessary you check your installation path. :)

Answer (score 0):

I am using Python 2.7 and a Windows 64-bit system. I was getting the same error for `lxml-3.8.0-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl` while doing `pip install lxml-3.8.0-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl`.

Run `pip install lxml` and it auto-detected and successfully installed the Win32 version (though my system is Windows-64 bit)

```
cd C:\Python27
pip install lxml

Collecting lxml
  Downloading lxml-3.8.0-cp27-cp27m-win32.whl (2.9MB)
    100% |################################| 2.9MB 20kB/s
Installing collected packages: lxml
Successfully installed lxml-3.8.0
```

So, I will go with @1man's answer.

Answer (score 0):

During [TensorFlow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TensorFlow) configuration I specified Python 3.6. But default, Python on my system is Python 2.7. Thus pip in my case means pip for 2.7. For me

```
pip3 install /tmp/tensorflow_pkg/NAME.whl
```

did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

In my case (Windows 64-bit, Python 2.7, and [Cygwin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cygwin)) the issue was with a missing `gcc`.

Using `apt-cyg install gcc-core` enabled me to then use `pip2 wheel ...` to install my [wheels](https://duckduckgo.com/html/?q=Wikipedia%20wheels) automatically.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it had to do with not having installed the [GDAL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GDAL) core previously. For a guide on how to install the GDAL and Basemap libraries go to *[GISPython](https://github.com/felipunky/GISPython/blob/master/README.md)*

Answer (score 0):

For me, it worked when I selected the correct bit of my Python version, *not* the one of my computer version.

Mine is 32 bit, and my computer is 64 bit. That was the problem and the 32 bit version of fixed it.

To be exact, here is the one that I downloaded and worked for me:

```
mysqlclient-1.3.13-cp37-cp37m-win32.whl
```

Once again, just make sure to chose your Python version of bits and not your system one.

Answer (score 0):

I tried a bunch of the stuff in previous answers to no avail.

Previously, I upgraded to pip 18.1, but I kept getting the following error when trying (for pyFltk):

```
>>from fltk import *

ImportError: DLL load failed %1 is not a valid Win32 Application
```

I was getting all sorts of errors about the *.whl file not being supported by my machine or something about being unable to remove the correct files from distutils.

I went back to my notes and they indicated that the whl file:

pyFltk-1.3.3.1-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl but I kept getting the error above sooo...

it required pip 9.0.3 to install.

I downgraded my version of pip to 9.0.3:

```
pip install pip=9.0.3
```

And the .whl file installed properly.

This is also related to: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19019720/importerror-dll-load-failed-1-is-not-a-valid-win32-application-but-the-dlls)

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to verify the installation of TensorFlow as specified [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip?lang=python3#package-location) on a newly created virtual environment on Python 3.6. On running:

```
pip3 install --ignore-installed --upgrade "/Users/Salman/Downloads/tensorflow-1.12.0-cp37-cp37m-macosx_10_13_x86_64.whl"
```

I get the error and/or warning:

> tensorflow-1.12.0-cp37-cp37m-macosx_10_13_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

Since I had previously upgraded from **pip** to **pip3**, I simply replaced **pip** with **pip3** as in:

```
pip3 install --ignore-installed --upgrade "/Users/Salman/Downloads/tensorflow-1.12.0-cp37-cp37m-macosx_10_13_x86_64.whl"
```

and it worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem

I downloaded the latest pip from https://pypi.org/project/pip/#files

And then....

```
pip install << downloaded file location >>
```

And then the [Pygame](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pygame) and [Kivy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kivy_(framework)) installation worked...

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was using Linux (Docker container), and tried to install Windows whl-package.

```
py3-none-win_amd64.whl
```

This obviously doesn't work, use e.g. "any" or "linux" -version for Docker/Linux instead of "win".

Answer (score -3):

All right, the problem is easy. [TensorFlow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TensorFlow) requires Python 3.4 - 3.7 and 64 bit. I see then you're using Python 2.7.

Read the TensorFlow install instructions on *[Install TensorFlow with pip](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip)*.