# hi, I'm trying to install scipy which is on my drive

Tags: scipy

I used the command "pip install scipy-0.16.0-cp34-cp34m-macosx_10_6_intel.macosx_10_9_intel.macosx_10_9_x86_64.macosx_10_10_intel.macosx_10_10_x86_64.whl"

but it keeps giving me this error

"scipy-0.16.0-cp34-cp34m-macosx_10_6_intel.macosx_10_9_intel.macosx_10_9_x86_64.macosx_10_10_intel.macosx_10_10_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform"

any help please?

Comment: Please add the *exact* error to your question.

Comment: consider using homebrew: https://joernhees.de/blog/2014/02/25/scientific-python-on-mac-os-x-10-9-with-homebrew/

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this question is a variation on [filename.whl is not supported wheel on this platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28568070/filename-whl-is-not-supported-wheel-on-this-platform)

I'm guessing you have Python 2.7 installed on your system, but the .whl you're trying to use is meant for Python 3. You can tell by the `cp34` in the .whl's filename.

(If you open a Terminal an type `python -V`
I suspect you will get something like `Python 2.7.10`.)

Try installing this file instead: [scipy 0.16.0 for Mac and Python 2.7](https://pypi.python.org/packages/cp27/s/scipy/scipy-0.16.0-cp27-none-macosx_10_6_intel.macosx_10_9_intel.macosx_10_9_x86_64.macosx_10_10_intel.macosx_10_10_x86_64.whl#md5=60e842bcf8b95affc19ef6f2a4bd5bb9). It is called `scipy-0.16.0-cp27-none-macosx_10_6_intel.macosx_10_9_intel.macosx_10_9_x86_64.macosx_10_10_intel.macosx_10_10_x86_64.whl` Note the `cp27` in the filename.

Comment: Please add that info to your question. I'll then remove my incorrect answer. Also add information about what OS version you are running to the question.