# Installing package using pip command

Tags: python

I am trying to install basemap using the pip command. My command is here ( I am using anaconda):

```
pip install "C:\Users\hh\Downloads\basemap-1.0.8-cp35-none-win32.whl"
```

The error message I get is:

```
basemap-1.0.8-cp35-none-win32.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

How would I fix this as I need to install base map. I already have python 3.5 and all the neccesary dependencies. I am using this post: [Basemap with Python 3.5 Anaconda on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35716830/basemap-with-python-3-5-anaconda-on-windows) as a reference.

Comment: You're wanting to install on a unix-like platform? That package shows it's for win32 platforms, hence the error that it's not supported on your platform. Look for a unix/linux version of that wheel. Looks you may have to build it from the source tarball, see: http://matplotlib.org/basemap/users/installing.html#installation

Comment: I want to install on windows 7.

Comment: Take the unix tag off the question and use the version that matches your windows platform.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a 64-bit version of Windows you should download the 64bit version package (basemap-1.0.8-cp35-none-win_amd64.whl)