# Python GEOS on windows 2010

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib-basemap, geos

I'm trying to install basemap(for matplotlib) on windows 2010 , but you must do it manually and you must have geos library installed.Sadly if you pip install geos you get a geos0.1 and basemap needs geos3 and above.I can find geos 3 and above but it seems it is not for windows.Is there a way to download geos version>3 on windows?

Comment: *always* use a generic [python] tag. Anyway, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42587648/5014455) seems pretty straightforward using `conda`, if you are willing. Probably the easiest way on Windows.

Comment: Cant do it without it , i dont have conda installed?

Comment: You *can* but using conda would be a lot easier

Comment: Thx i will check it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future viewers , cause osgeo and basemap on windows users is a real pain , to install them :

1. pip install pyproj
2. go to this site https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/ and download wheel file for **gdal** library and **basemap** library.(you need to download the correct file fitting your python version)
3. Install via pip shapely and then basemap.(pip install DownloadedFileName.whl)
4. If you are making an application you will need to add a blank **init** file in basemap's folder(this is only if you need to compile basemap library for your application)

All the above is if you need these libraries as bindings , if not you can use simple installers(osgeos4w) witch come with seperate consoles.