# Pip doesn't install Twisted on Windows

Tags: python, windows, pip, twisted

I am trying to install Twisted on a Windows 8 computer. On the official Twisted website, there is only one Wheel file for windows.

https://twistedmatrix.com/trac/wiki/Downloads

I already installed Zope and PyWin32.

But when I do :

```
pip install Twisted-16.0.0-cp27-none-win_amd64.whl
```

I get :

```
Twisted-16.0.0-cp27-none-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform
```

I have seen and tried the solutions of these 2 topics :

[filename.whl is not supported wheel on this platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28568070/filename-whl-is-not-supported-wheel-on-this-platform)
and [How do I install a Python package with a .whl file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27885397/how-do-i-install-a-python-package-with-a-whl-file)

pip is up-to-date, CPython2.7 is installed, I tried with

```
python -m pip intall
```

and

```
path\to\pip install
```

None of it worked.

What am I missing, what have I not tried ?

Comment: Are you using a 64 bit version of Python 2.7 to match the 64 bit wheel that you're installing?

Comment: My gosh ! It's a 32bit version, I'm installing a 64 bits right now ! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own post.

As Rod Hyde commented, only the 64 bit version of python is officialy supported by Twisted.

Edit to answer anatoly : 
Under the Windows Download section of Twisted, it is written "Twisted 16.0.0 for Python 2.7 **64 bits**"

Comment: Is there a proof link?

Comment: Well the only thing I can come up with is this : https://twistedmatrix.com/trac/wiki/Downloads, Under the Windows section it is written Twisted 16.0.0 for Python 2.7 **64 bits**

Comment: 32-bit are still supported. Just not available yet - https://twistedmatrix.com/pipermail/twisted-python/2016-April/030266.html

Answer (score 8):

Use this link. http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#twisted.

Its a repository for unofficial modules, but works every time for me. Use win32 version.

Comment: Thanks ! But installing a 64 bit version of Python fixed the problem !

Comment: A quick suggestion. bookmark that link as many modules are not available for windows directly. Might be helpful in future...

Comment: I always go to that link when pip fails to install a library ... which happens often on windows.

Comment: install Twisted from its unofficial repository for 64 bit version of windows 10 and now its working fine for me.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem too but I solved it as follow:
Open the Anaconda Prompt as administrator (For `Windows10`: open `cortana`/write `Anaconda Prompt`/choose `Run as Administrator`)

You should go to the path of Anaconda, for me was like:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>cd ..
C:\WINDOWS>cd..
C:\>cd  ProgramData
C:\ProgramData>cd Anaconda3
C:\ProgramData>Anaconda3>
```

Then you should run the following command

```
C:\ProgramData>Anaconda3>conda install -c anaconda twisted
```

At some point it asks

```
Proceed ([y]/n)?
```

type `y`. Now `twisted` is installed.

Comment: Thanks that worked for me. I think the solution is to use conda instead of pip.

Answer (score 1):

The Windows XP that was building 32-bit Twisted wheels was decommissioned, so no builds are being built. People propose to install 32-bit toolchain on 64-bit Windows builder, so they might get back soon.

See https://twistedmatrix.com/pipermail/twisted-python/2016-March/030227.html

And https://twistedmatrix.com/trac/ticket/8314

Answer (score 1):

This is very simple on windows. You need to install Twisted seperately.

Just 2 steps:

```
pip install pipwin
pipwin install Twisted
```

Answer (score 0):

The recommended way is to run pip install Twisted, preferably inside a virtualenv.

If you are installing on macOS, pip install Twisted[macos_platform] will install the macOS-specific requirements.

If you are installing on Windows, pip install Twisted[windows_platform] will install the Windows-specific requirements.

https://twistedmatrix.com/trac/wiki/Downloads

thanks u...