# Pip doesn't install Twisted on Windows 10

Tags: python, pip, twisted

I m trying to install binance api on windows 10 and get this error:

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
 command: 'c:\users\nikho\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\nikho\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-udog8jg5\\twisted_baf4607a0b15400dbdad7c4c4d71a93f\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\nikho\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-udog8jg5\\twisted_baf4607a0b15400dbdad7c4c4d71a93f\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\nikho\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-qxfi2_c7\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\nikho\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\Include\Twisted'
```

And I saw this post [Pip doesn't install Twisted on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36279141/pip-doesnt-install-twisted-on-windows). I tried it but doesnt work (also try to install 64bit version and 32bit version, my computer is 64)

Then I download from this site the last version: [https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#twisted](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#twisted)
I run it (doble click) and nothing happend, also I run in terminal like this and doesnt work:

```
pip install  Twisted-19.2.1-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl
```

Anyone knows how to fix it

Answer (score 0):

Did you try :
`pip install Twisted` or `pip install Twisted --user`

Comment: and did you try to uninstall (automatically or manually) the Twisted's files installed in your PC, and install again with pip

Comment: I think the same but look this: WARNING: Skipping twisted as it is not installed. is the return of pip uninstall twisted

Comment: this error depend surely to your python version, so if you got an error after this, try to install an older python version to see if this works

Comment: which python version did you use ?

Comment: I solved it, I just reinstall all of visual studio and then works fine