# Error: "anymodule.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform." even the version of module and python both are same

Tags: windows, python-3.x, pip, environment-variables, platform

Tried installing python modules but error appears "anymodule.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform." even the version of module and python both are same.

Comment: Make sure the name of the wheel file is kept the same. The program will say it is invalid if you rename it after downloading it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your cmd:

*python -m pip install --upgrade pip*

Your deprecated pip version is causing this error. Once you have done this, try

*pip install your_wheel_file*

For more reference see [filename.whl is not supported wheel on this platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28568070/filename-whl-is-not-supported-wheel-on-this-platform)

Regards!