# How to install python packages from whl files

Tags: python, pip, package

I have downloaded `pycairo` from this [web-page](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pycairo) and tried to install it with `pip`:

```
pip install pycairo-1.10.0-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl
```

Which returned:

```
pycairo-1.10.0-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
Storing debug log for failure in C:\Users\user\pip\pip.log
```

`pip.log` shows this:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
C:\Python27\Scripts\pip run on 11/05/16 10:46:49
pycairo-1.10.0-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 122, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 257, in run
    InstallRequirement.from_line(name, None))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\req.py", line 167, in from_line
    raise UnsupportedWheel("%s is not a supported wheel on this platform." % wheel.filename)
UnsupportedWheel: pycairo-1.10.0-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

I checked supported pip tags using:

```
import pip
print pip.pep425tags.get_supported()
```

The output was:

```
[('cp27', 'none', 'win_amd64'), ('cp27', 'none', 'any'), ('cp2', 'none', 'any'), ('cp26', 'none', 'any'), ('cp25', 'none', 'any'), ('cp24', 'none', 'any'), ('cp23', 'none', 'any'), ('cp22', 'none', 'any'), ('cp21', 'none', 'any'), ('cp20','none', 'any'), ('py27', 'none', 'any'), ('py2', 'none', 'any'), ('py26', 'none', 'any'), ('py25', 'none', 'any'), ('py24', 'none', 'any'), ('py23', 'none', 'any'), ('py22', 'none', 'any'), ('py21', 'none', 'any'), ('py20', 'none', 'any')]
```

Since `('cp27', 'none', 'win_amd64')` is listed there, I expect to install `pycairo-1.10.0-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl` with no problem, but I can't. Is there anything else which I miss?

Comment: Is it possible you have multiple versions of Python installed?  If you do `python -m pip install [your wheel]` do you get the same error?

Comment: @BrenBarn No, I have one version of python, but I found out that my pip was old. Updating pip solved the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38623149/1626977). My `pip` version was old. I upgraded it with:

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

Everything works fine now.