# Tensorflow Installation : Both python2 and python3 are installed on macOS.

Tags: macos, tensorflow

I have both python2 and python3 installed on my system(macos sierra).

I tried installing latest version of tensrorflow using pip. It's working for python 3 but not for python2.

I am getting following error "tensorflow-0.12.1-py2-none-any.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform."

Comment: I just tried it on my Mac using an anaconda environment with py2.7 and it installed fine. This [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/a/36046420/5587428) says an out-of-date pip might be a problem. Perhaps try updating pip

Answer (score 0):

If you have pip version 8.1 or higher, `pip install tensorflow` command should work. Otherwise, you may install using this command:
`pip install https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/cpu/tensorflow-0.12.1-py2-none-any.whl` If neither of these do not work, you may need to update your pip version as suggested by @RobR