# errors installing scipy and numpy mkl in windows ,python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, scipy, win64

I have downloaded the packages of numpy+mkl and scipy from the following link http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/ and tried to use

pip install numpy-1.11.3+mkl-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl

from the same directory where the wheel file exists I am getting an error like

numpy-1.11.3+mkl-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

and when installing numpy 
pip install numpy i am not getting any errors but when i am trying to

pip install scipy

there are some packages blas and etc were not found so i have downloaded the packages for numpy mkl and scipy from the above link and trying to install them but of no use please get me out of this problem --- Thank you!

Comment: Try a 32 bit wheel.

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28568070/filename-whl-is-not-supported-wheel-on-this-platform

Answer (score 2):

you may use 32 bit. Try to install numpy‑1.11.3+mkl‑cp27‑cp27m‑win32.whl

Comment: yeah it worked, python 2.7 installed in my sys is 32 bit and I realised it after seeing your post  thank you very much