# Cannot pip install sklearn for Python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, scikit-learn, pip

First, I downloaded the numpy+nlk whl file [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy) and did

```
python3 -m pip install numpy‑1.11.3+mkl‑cp36‑none-any.whl
```

I renamed thanks to this tip: [filename.whl is not supported wheel on this platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28568070/filename-whl-is-not-supported-wheel-on-this-platform)

But when I do

```
python3 -m pip install sklearn
```

I get Original error was: cannot import name 'multiarray'

I've tried unistalling and reinstalling numpy, but I have no idea how to fix this.

Comment: Can't you simply install numpy with `python3 -m pip install numpy`? Or, if `sklearn` has its dependencies set correctly, only install sklearn, and it should automatically install numpy as well.

Comment: it says requirement already satisfied when I install numpy and if i uninstall it i can't install sklearn

Comment: Basic troubleshooting first then: can you `import numpy` if your run Python?

Answer (score 2):

I just uploaded the windows wheels for scikit-learn 0.18.2 and Python 3.6 to PyPi: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/scikit-learn/0.18.2 Can you try again and give the full traceback if that still does not work?

Comment: Not sure if it makes a different but I'm on a Mac

Comment: Which version ? There is a wheel for OSX for Python 3.6 see: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/scikit-learn/0.18.2

Answer (score 1):

If you have installed pip then follow the given steps:

1. upgrade pip to the latest version
2. install

```bash
pip install numpy scipy scikit-learn  
pip install sklearn
```