# xxx.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform

Tags: python, numpy

I want to install numpy which I downloaded from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy and I tried two files:

- `numpy‑1.13.1+mkl‑cp36‑cp36m‑win32.whl`
- `numpy‑1.13.1+mkl‑cp36‑cp36m‑win_amd64.whl`

I got `xxx.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform`.

As I looked for a solution, I found this useful link: [filename.whl is not supported wheel on this platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28568070/filename-whl-is-not-supported-wheel-on-this-platform)

I've tried every suggested solution from that question but nothing works. What I've done already:

1. I followed @gregorio099's comment to check the version of Python and I
   get ('32bit', 'WindowsPE')
2. I followed @aldel's comment to update pip and I get requirement already up-to-date: pip in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages
3. I also follow @Arun Naudiyal's answer

   ```
   import pip
   print(pip.pep425tags.get_supported())
   ```

   and get:

   ```
   [('cp36', 'cp36m', 'win32'), ('cp36', 'none', 'win32'), ('py3', 'none', 'win32'), ('cp36', 'none', 'any'), ('cp3', 'none', 'any'), ('py36', 'none', 'any'), ('py3', 'none', 'any'), ('py35', 'none', 'any'), ('py34', 'none', 'any'), ('py33', 'none', 'any'), ('py32', 'none', 'any'), ('py31', 'none', 'any'), ('py30', 'none', 'any')]
   ```

For more information, I use Python 3.6.2 on Windows 10. I don't have C:\Python so I used these commands to find a directory for my python

```
import os
import sys
os.path.dirname(sys.executable)
```

and I get `'C:\\Users\\my_name\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36-32'`

I'm not sure whether this is a source of the problem.

Comment: assuming you have both python2 and 3 on the same pc, you need to make sure you are updating the right pythons pip: `py -3.6 -m pip install --upgrade pip`

Comment: @JamesKent I get `Requested Python version (3.6) not installed`

Comment: it looks like your installation paths are a bit messed up, normally python would be in a "C:\Python36" folder rather than in an appdata folder, so it may not be properly installed (as far as the py.exe program is concerned, therefore cannot find it. instead look in `C:\Users\my_name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32` for both your python executable, and for a scripts folder, either put in the full path to the python exe for the pip command, or run the command from that directory, then change into the scripts directory for the pip command, or use the full path to that folder

Comment: @JamesKent I tried to uninstall and then install Python again. This time I changed the directory to `C:\Python36` by myself and then I follow the same procedure as above. I still got the same problem. I think the problem is my pip version. Finally, I changed from `pip install numpy-1.13.1+mkl-cp36-cp36m-win32.whl` to `pip3.6 install numpy-1.13.1+mkl-cp36-cp36m-win32.whl` and it's work!!! Thank you very much for your help.