# how to install pillow without net in linux?

Tags: linux, pip, installation, python-imaging-library

I want to install pillow on linux,but I don't have internet.
I try to download [pillow](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow/4.3.0) and pip install it

```
sudo pip install Pillow-4.3.0-cp27-cp27m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
```

and get error...

```
Pillow-4.3.0-cp27-cp27m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

It's strange...

linux -> x84_64.

python-> 2.7

Sincerely.

Comment: Verify that you python is 64bit: `python -c "import struct; print(struct.calcsize('P') * 8)"`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [filename.whl is not supported wheel on this platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28568070/filename-whl-is-not-supported-wheel-on-this-platform)

Comment: my python is 64bit, and I tried to install all of the Pillow package. I got the same error.

Comment: One option is to build from source.