# cx_freeze not a supported wheel

Tags: python, python-3.x, cx-freeze

I am currently having a problem with python as I am trying to install cx_Freeze.

Here is the error:

```
cx_Freeze-5.0.2-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

I am currently using python version 3.6.6
and I am on windows 10 64bit with visual studio build tools 2017 installed.

Does anyone know how to fix this as I am currently stumped?

EDIT:

so I just found out that I have 32-bit python installed but that's not the problem because I just downloaded the 32-bit version of cx_freeze and it is still giving me the same error

Comment: This might help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28568070/filename-whl-is-not-supported-wheel-on-this-platform

Comment: Do you have the most recent `pip` version?

Comment: yes i do have the most recent pip version

Comment: and to answer jihan1008 i already had a look at that question the problem there was he was using the wrong version however i am using the right version as the wheel file is for python 3.6

Answer (score 0):

pip install cx_Freeze==5.0.2 is what I just used and it seems to have fixed it.