# Python wheel does not install in a supposedly compatible windows system

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-wheel

I have a Python project for which I create a wheel on system A. This wheel does not install on system B using pip but fails with the error message

> ... is not a supported wheel on this platform

As far as I can tell, the platforms in system A and B are the same in the relevant details. I could not find comprehensive documentation on the subject via google. So my questions:

1. For a given machine, what is the best way to get the string that describes the platform data that is used in the pip file (e.g. "cp36-cp36m-win_amd64")?
2. What is the complete set of parameters pip checks for a target wheel
   and platform to determine compatibility?
3. How can I create a wheel that can be installed on many platforms at
   once, similar to "manylinux" but for Windows/Mac OSx?

Details:

I am creating the wheel using the command

```
python setup.py bdist_wheel
```

This generates the file

```
my_project_name-1.0.1-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl
```

On my system, I can install the wheel using

```
pip install my_project_name-1.0.1-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl
```

On the target system, the exact same command line on the exact same file yields the following error:

```
 my_project_name-1.0.1-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform
```

Both systems are 64-bit Windows 7.

Trying to get platform data on my system yields

```
>>> import platform
>>> platform.machine()
'AMD64'
>>> platform.platform()
'Windows-7-6.1.7601-SP1'
>>> platform.processor()
'Intel64 Family 6 Model 60 Stepping 3, GenuineIntel'
>>> platform.python_version()
'3.6.0'
```

Trying to get platform data on the target system yields

```
import platform
platform.machine()
'AMD64'
platform.platform()
'Windows-7-6.1.7601-SP1'
platform.processor()
'Intel64 Family 6 Model 60 Stepping 3, GenuineIntel'
platform.python_version()
'3.6.3'
```

This is almost identical (except the Python sub-sub-version - should this make any difference?) and so I'm clueless as to what prevents the wheel installation on the target system.

Comment: Did you try all answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28568070/filename-whl-is-not-supported-wheel-on-this-platform

Comment: Thank you. I attempted some of them, but not all. I am trying now the "all-none" workaround and checking whether Python itself is 32 or 64 bits (I did not realize the "AMD64" referred to the Python version and not the CPU).

Comment: See also https://docs.python.org/3/library/platform.html#platform.architecture