# Installing Python Client for Driverless AI

Tags: driverless-ai

I'm trying to install the python client for h2o driverless, but get this message when i try to sudo pip install this whl file i got from the PY_CLIENT on the UI. This is the message i get. Does this work only on Linux systems ?

**h2oai_client-1.3.1-py3-none-any.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.**

Answer (score 0):

this may be related to your version of pip, please see this other generic question on your error [filename.whl is not supported wheel on this platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28568070/filename-whl-is-not-supported-wheel-on-this-platform)

DAI does does work on linux systems for a full list of compatible installation platforms please see the user guide: http://docs.h2o.ai/driverless-ai/latest-stable/docs/userguide/installing.html