# Installing pytorch on python 3.7 installed ubuntu gives an error

Tags: python, pip, pytorch

Hi all am new to pytorch and trying to run a model based on pytorch.My workstation has python 3.7 installed.So as per pytorch official site when I try to install python with below command

`pip3 install http://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu/torch-0.4.1.post2-cp37-cp37m-linux_x86_64.whl`

It gives error like below

```
torch-0.4.1.post2-cp37-cp37m-linux_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

Can any one help me with this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [filename.whl is not supported wheel on this platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28568070/filename-whl-is-not-supported-wheel-on-this-platform)

Comment: Question has nothing to do with `jupyter-notebook` or `flask` - kindly do not spam the tags (removed).