# pycairo-1.15.4-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform

Tags: python, pip, pycairo

I have the following error when I try to install pycairo on Windows:

`pycairo-1.15.4-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.`

From [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28568070/filename-whl-is-not-supported-wheel-on-this-platform), I guess the error is related to the file version I'm installing. But none of [these binaries](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pycairo) worked for me.

Comment: What Python version? 32-bit or 64-bit python?

Comment: `python -c "import pip._internal; print(pip._internal.pep425tags.get_supported())"`

Comment: @phd Thank's for your help! It works now. I downloaded the corresponding binary file to my python version (64 bit). The reason It didn't work before is that I forgot to move the download file to my current folder and didn't notice the error message `looks like a filename but the file doesn't exist`.