# cx_Freeze is not a supported wheel on this platform

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, cx-freeze

I'm trying to install cx_freeze to convert a tkinter to exe , but when I type

```
 pip install cx_Freeze-5.1.1-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl
```

it shows: 
cx_Freeze-5.1.1-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

Comment: What Python version and OS are you using?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [filename.whl is not supported wheel on this platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28568070/filename-whl-is-not-supported-wheel-on-this-platform)

Comment: You have to download the wheel file matches with your Python version and OS architecture (32bit or 64bit).

Answer (score 0):

you must have downloaded the wrong version, very simple to check,simply run:

pip -V

or

pip3 -V

it'll print out the path for python site-package, something like this:

[image]

python37-32 means that you need to download whl file with ****cp37‑win32 in the filename