# MontagePy-1.0.1-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform

Tags: python, pip, python-wheel, astropy

Python 3.7 is installed on my 64 bit machine. When I try running `pip3 install`, I get the message that the wheel file is not supported on my platform.

Here's what I've checked so far :

- `cp36` in the file name means that I need Python 3.6 or above, so 3.7 fits the bill
- my python installation is 64 bits as well (https://stackoverflow.com/a/36158157/3128109)
- Since platform requirements are taken from the name of the file, I tried changing the name to `MontagePy-1.0.1-cp36-none-any.whl`, but I get the same error.
- `pip --version` says `pip 19.0.3 from /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pip (python 3.4)`. Could this be the root of the problem? If so, how  would I get pip to run with 3.7 rather than 3.4?

What could cause this platform incompatibility?

---

The debug log says

```
/usr/bin/pip3 run on Fri Mar  1 14:09:04 2019
MontagePy-1.0.1-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 122, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 257, in run
    InstallRequirement.from_line(name, None))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 168, in from_line
    raise UnsupportedWheel("%s is not a supported wheel on this platform." % wheel.filename)
pip.exceptions.UnsupportedWheel: MontagePy-1.0.1-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

Comment: No, `cp36` in the file name means that you need Python 3.6 **exactly**. Use Python 3.6 or download a wheel for 3.7.

Comment: You could also try installing from the source package if they don't have a wheel for Python 3.7 yet.

Comment: @Iguananaut That's a good idea. Unfortunately, their source package only has a build command for the wheel file.

Comment: @usernumber Did you find a solution? Is there a way to modify the source code to make it work on a higher version? I'm trying to get it on 3.10, but it just won't work