# What is the correct Docker Baseimage for a manylinux1_x86_64.whl?

Tags: python, linux, docker, pip, gurobi

I'm trying to pip install gurobipy in my docker. When I used pip install with the given index `pip install -i https://pypi.gurobi.com gurobipy`, i got a "no matching distribution found" error when building the image. So I decided to use the correct wheel file directly. This left me with `ERROR: gurobipy-9.1.1-cp38-cp38-manylinux1_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.`

- I tried using `python:3.6`, `python:3.8` and ubuntu latest with python3 as base images with the corresponding .whl files

  - Besides `pip install -i *url*`, I used the following .whl files for the corresponding python versions(all can be found here: https://pypi.gurobi.com/gurobipy/):

    - python:3.8: gurobipy-9.1.1-cp38-cp38-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
    - python:3.6: gurobipy-9.1.1-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
- I checked the python architecture - it's 64. Bit. When I used `pip install -i *url*` in my pycharm Python 3.8 venv (64-Bit), everything worked out perfectly fine.
- The directorys inside the .whl file can be found in the attached screenshot.[image: file structure inside whl file]

A similar issue was adressed at [MontagePy-1.0.1-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54945866/montagepy-1-0-1-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1-x86-64-whl-is-not-a-supported-wheel-on-thi) without a sufficient anwser.

Gurobi is widely used and I couldn't find others with similar problems regarding gurobi, so I'm pretty sure i messed something up in my dockerfile. Am I using the wrong baseimage, Python version or missing any requirements?

I'm using the following dockerfile and requirements.

Dockerfile:
The outcommented lines i usually run in the terminal of the running container.

```
FROM python:3.8

WORKDIR /

COPY . ./Wueexam_optimization
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install -r Wueexam_optimization/optimization/requirements.txt
#RUN pip install --extra-index-url https://pypi.gurobi.com gurobipy
#RUN pip install https://pypi.gurobi.com/gurobipy/gurobipy-9.1.1-cp38-cp38-manylinux1_x86_64.whl

ENV PYTHONPATH /

WORKDIR /Wueexam_optimization/optimization
CMD ["python3","-u","app.py"]
```

Requirements:

```
flask
flask-cors
flask-sqlalchemy
Flask-SQLAlchemy
numpy == 1.19.3
pandas
mysqlclient
openpyxl
pulp
pymysql
cryptography
```

Comment: Can you include your DOCKERFILE?

Comment: It's ok for me to use `python:3.8` as base image to install `pip install -i https://pypi.gurobi.com gurobipy`, maybe you need to show your CPU type.

Comment: I included the dockerfile and requirements. I'm using a Mac with Apple Silicon M1 for the build. Maybe there is the problem. Until now I tought this doesn't make a difference in the docker, since everything is build on the base image, or did I misunderstand ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The m1 might cause Problems during the Build

Answer (score 0):

The problem was caused by a incompatibility with the Apple M1. Building the same docker file with a intel processor worked perfectly fine.