# How to install a specific version of PyQt5 on linux

Tags: python, linux, raspberry-pi, pyqt5

I was trying to install PyQt5 version 5.7.1 on my raspberry pi but I have an issue about installation. When I try:

`sudo pip3 install pyqt5==5.7.1`  or

`sudo python3 -m pip install PyQt5==5.7.1`

I get error like:

**Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://www.piwheels.org/simple**
**Collecting pyqt5==5.7.1**
  **Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyqt5==5.7.1 (from versions: 5.14.0, 5.14.1)**
**No matching distribution found for pyqt5==5.7.1**

Then I try to install it manually. I download the version on https://pypi.org/project/PyQt5/5.7.1/ and try to install with pip

`sudo pip3 install PyQt5-5.7.1-5.7.1-cp34.cp35.cp36-abi3-manylinux1_x86_64.whl`
(I got ERROR)

**PyQt5-5.7.1-5.7.1-cp34.cp35.cp36-abi3-manylinux1_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.**

What can I do?

Comment: Which version python are you using?

Comment: python3 -> 3.7.3
python2 -> 2.7.16

Comment: If you see the Python versions in the download page of the wheel, it says only 3.4, 3.5, 3.6 are supported (these also appear in the .whl file name). You could perhaps try with one of these versions.

Comment: Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/q/28568070/5987698

Comment: I install python 3.6.8 and try to install with:  `sudo /usr/local/bin/python3.6 -m pip install /Downloads/PyQt5-5.7.1-5.7.1-cp34.cp35.cp36-abi3-manylinux1_x86_64.whl`  but I got same error: 
(PyQt5-5.7.1-5.7.1-cp34.cp35.cp36-abi3-manylinux1_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
You are using pip version 18.1, however version 19.3.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.)

Comment: I try to install 5.8 version with python 3.7.3 with PyQt5-5.8-5.8.0-cp34.cp35.cp36.cp37-abi3-manylinux1_x86_64.whl .  It still says  **not a supported wheel on this platform** What can I do?

Comment: Did you check if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36046420/5987698) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36158157/5987698) are of any help?

Comment: I have 32 bit OS, did x86_64 means 64 bit?

Comment: Yes, it does. Look for _x86 or _win32.

Comment: Im on Linux Debian. Can I use _win32 ? Doesn't win stands for windows?