# Python 3.9 x64 does the wrong pip install (x32)

Tags: python, pip, 64-bit

I have just installed python 3.9 x64, and during the install I have selected to include pip.

I can see that I indeed have x64 version (running `import struct;print( 8 * struct.calcsize("P"))` in python does indeed return 64).

I run pip by calling `Python39\python.exe -m pip install numpy`, however I can see that it installs the x32 version of numpy:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hmXEM.png)

and if I run python, `import numpy` I get the following error: `OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application`

How can I make it so that pip installs x64 versions?

Comment: You can manually download the 64-bit whl file here: https://pypi.org/project/numpy/#files

Comment: I did, but it wont install it properly: `C:\Windows\System32>pip install "C:\Users\XXXX\Downloads\numpy-1.20.2+mkl-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl"
ERROR: numpy-1.20.2+mkl-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.`

Comment: Maybe your pip is out of date. Try python -m pip install --upgrade pip and then installing it again. Also, are you absolutely _sure_ that your Python is 64-bit? pip should try to install the 64-bit version if your Python install is 64-bit. Also you could try removing +mkl in the filename because [apparently](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37046355) just having the wrong filename will fail.

Comment: Also - do you have 32-bit Python installed on your computer somewhere else? I noticed in your pip command in the comments that you just ran pip install, which could invoke the 32-bit version if you have 32-bit Python. If that is the case, make sure you're invoking the 64-bit pip with `path/to/new/python/python -m pip install`

Comment: I did the upgrade, and it is running the x64. The way I checked is that I am running `path\to\python.exe` and then I do check its x64, then when calling pip I do it by `path\to\python.exe -m pip ..` and still no luck..

Comment: That's really strange...you might want to reinstall Python then, something might be corrupted