# ERROR: bcrypt-4.0.1-cp36-abi3-manylinux_2_28_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform

Tags: python, python-3.x, installation, pip

I have seen [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28568070/error-filename-whl-is-not-a-supported-wheel-on-this-platform), but I'm doing `pipenv run pip3 install Resources/UI_Mgmtpackage/*.whl`     which the case is slightly different (than normal pip install)

that I'm importing program from personal file , set up machine
[image]

seems is also the  python version not fit, what else can I input instead?

Comment: cause just put   `scipy‑0.15.1‑cp27‑none‑win_amd64.whl` seems not quit address  my issue

Comment: Pls don't post picutres of console output. Always copy/paste the text

Answer (score 3, accepted):

python is 3.8 and you are trying to install a cp36, i.e. python 3.6 whl which is incompatible. Make sure to use python 3.6 or download a cp38 whl file

Comment: so, if I redownload the python version to  python 3.6, then `pipenv run pip3 install Resources/UI_Mgmtpackage/*.whl`  could the problem?

Comment: you need to download and install python3.6 and install pipenv to that. Make sure that that you are actually calling pipenv for python 3.6