# Wheel not supported on this platform - how to fix this?

Tags: python-wheel

I am trying to install from a wheel, and I am getting the following error running pip:

```
>>pip install quickfix-1.15.1-cp37-cp37m-win32.whl

ERROR: quickfix-1.15.1-cp37-cp37m-win32.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

Although most things have installed just fine, this has happened with several different files, and I am wondering if I may have a problem with my system.
I am using:
Windows 10 pro

and I have tried this both through the Administrator powershell, as well as the powershell initiated through Anaconda Navigator.  Any suggestions or advice would be appreciated.

```
>>pip install quickfix-1.15.1-cp37-cp37m-win32.whl

ERROR: quickfix-1.15.1-cp37-cp37m-win32.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

I was expecting a message saying that the quickfix had installed

Comment: No Python or wheel expert, but this is probably not quickfix specific, e.g. check https://stackoverflow.com/q/28568070/4962355 . Did you try 64bit? "win32" in the filename is probably referring to the architecture which should probably be win64 on Windows 10 Pro? Not sure though.

Answer (score 0):

I created an environment with python 3.7 strictly to do this.  When I fired up my powershell under this environment and double checked the  python version, I saw 3.11
This was the source of my problem.  When I went through and made sure 3.7 was the version I had in the environment, my file installed right away.

Thank you, Christopher John for putting me on the right track!