# I can`t run my scrapy1.0.3

Tags: python, scrapy

```
>>>import scrapy
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "D:\SoftWare\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\__init__.py", line 56, in
<module>
    from scrapy.spider import Spider
  File "D:\SoftWare\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spider.py", line 7, in <mo
dule>
    from scrapy.http import Request
  File "D:\SoftWare\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\http\__init__.py", line 11
, in <module>
    from scrapy.http.request.form import FormRequest
  File "D:\SoftWare\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\http\request\form.py", lin
e 9, in <module>
    import lxml.html
  File "D:\SoftWare\Python27\lib\site-packages\lxml\html\__init__.py", line 42,
in <module>
    from lxml import etree
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 不是有效的 Win32 应用程序。
```

**This is what I had installed :pip list**

```
aniso8601 (1.0.0)
cffi (1.2.1)
characteristic (14.3.0)
cryptography (1.0.1)
cssselect (0.9.1)
enum34 (1.0.4)
field (0.2.0)
Flask (0.10.1)
Flask-RESTful (0.3.4)
Flask-Script (2.0.5)
Flask-SQLAlchemy (2.0)
idna (2.0)
ipaddress (1.0.14)
item (0.0.3)
itsdangerous (0.24)
Jinja2 (2.8)
libxml2-python (2.7.7)
lxml (3.4.4)
MarkupSafe (0.23)
mysql-connector-python (2.0.4)
MySQL-python (1.2.5)
PIL (1.1.7)
Pillow (2.9.0)
pip (7.1.2)
pyasn1 (0.1.8)
pyasn1-modules (0.0.7)
pycparser (2.14)
pyOpenSSL (0.15.1)
pytils (0.3)
pytz (2015.4)
pywin32 (219)
queuelib (1.4.2)
requests (2.7.0)
Scrapy (1.0.3)
selection (0.0.11)
service-identity (14.0.0)
setuptools (18.3.2)
six (1.9.0)
SQLAlchemy (1.0.8)
Twisted (15.4.0)
w3lib (1.12.0)
weblib (0.1.15)
Werkzeug (0.10.4)
WTForms (2.0.2)
zope.interface (4.1.2)
```

**My system is WIN7 x64 , Python 2.7.10 win32**
I think I had already installed what Scrapy require but I can`t run it.
I had tried to install 0.24.2 (lower version) but the problem can not be sloved

Comment: Can you translate the error message `DLL load failed: %1 不是有效的 Win32 应用程序。` into English for us?

Comment: You can get Sysinternals tools from Microsoft and use Process Monitor to log all Python's activity to get an insight on what is happening when that library is loaded.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application. But the DLL's are there](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19019720/importerror-dll-load-failed-1-is-not-a-valid-win32-application-but-the-dlls)

Comment: Sorry ,`DLL load failed: %1 不是有效的 Win32 应用程序。`   means **ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.**

Answer (score 1):

The solution is that you need some other requirements to install when using Scrapy on Windows because of a Bug of Twisted. You can read more about it in the [docs](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/install.html#windows).

If you go through all the steps you will see that you need to install [pywin32](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/) too. Alternatively you can look at the installation instructions [here](http://www.feedbackward.com/content/scrapy_install.pdf) because it is sometimes a bit more complicated. I used this doc for Windows and it works.

Comment: when I install pywin32 32-bit  follow your suggestion,`Traceback (most recent call last): File "<string>", line 408, in install File "<string>", line 221, in RegisterPythonwin WindowsError: [Error 5] close failed in file object destructor: sys.excepthook is missing lost sys.stderr` **how to solve it Can you help me**  Other requirements like openSSL , Twisted ,zope.interface.....I have installed.

Comment: Did you install it with the manual from here: http://www.feedbackward.com/content/scrapy_install.pdf ?