# Python 2.7 error import ROOT

Tags: python, root-framework

I installed root.exe in the folder C:\root_v5.34.36, folder C:\root_v5.34.36\bin which contains ROOT.py

When I started a Jupiter Notebook (anaconda), I write :

```
import sys
sys.path.append("C:\root_v5.34.36\bin")
```

Then

```
import ROOT
```

And it displays :

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-b332e25ada1f> in <module>()
----> 1 import ROOT

ImportError: No module named ROOT
```

What's wrong?

Comment: do you have a file `__init__.py` in the directory where `ROOT.py` is?

Comment: try `sys.path.append("C:\root_v5.34.36\")`. Or you should get the right dir.

Comment: @fedorqui no, just the folder bin which contains lot of .dll, .py etc...

Comment: @ Alexander Yau Same error without \bin

Comment: Check : [this](https://root.cern.ch/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?t=17414)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing the root bin path to `sys.path.append("C:\\root_v5.34.36\\bin")`

Comment: Seems to be the solution, thanks! Right now, I've got new problem...

"ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 isn't a valid win32 application."

Comment: Check this : [ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application. But the DLL's are there](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19019720/importerror-dll-load-failed-1-is-not-a-valid-win32-application-but-the-dlls) . It seems to be the same problem

Comment: Find an easier way => install anaconda 32 bits on my 64 bits OS, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the file `thisroot.bat` usually found in the `config` folder of the ROOT directory before starting the notebook application.

This should be done by opening a powershell and typing:

```
cd  C:\root_v5.34.36
.\config\thisroot.bat
C:\WhereverTheJupyterNotebookApplicationIs\JupyterNotebook.exe
```