# PyQt5 conflict with matplotlib in PyCharm

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt5

I have installed PyQt5 using pip install pyqt5.  Installation is successful.  A pip install of matplotlib says all requirements have been met.  When I then run matplotlib I receive the flowing error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 6, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 115, in <module>
    _backend_mod, new_figure_manager, draw_if_interactive, _show = pylab_setup()
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\__init__.py", line 62, in pylab_setup
    [backend_name], 0)
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_qt5agg.py", line 15, in <module>
    from .backend_qt5 import (
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_qt5.py", line 19, in <module>
    import matplotlib.backends.qt_editor.figureoptions as figureoptions
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\qt_editor\figureoptions.py", line 20, in <module>
    import matplotlib.backends.qt_editor.formlayout as formlayout
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\qt_editor\formlayout.py", line 54, in <module>
    from matplotlib.backends.qt_compat import QtGui, QtWidgets, QtCore
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\qt_compat.py", line 140, in <module>
    from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

Searching states that the installed packages are likely different bit version (eg. 32bit when I need 54 bit).  How can I fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application. But the DLL's are there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19019720/importerror-dll-load-failed-1-is-not-a-valid-win32-application-but-the-dlls)

Comment: I can import matplotlib but I cannot import pyplot.  The link addresses openCV library which I am not using

Comment: But I think the answers still apply. The point is you have some incompatible binaries installed. This may happen if you installed e.g. matplotlib for 64bit, but pyqt for 32bit or so.

Answer (score 0):

if you do not use pyqt and matplotlib together, then try to install conda and separate their environments. I encountered such a problem and I did so. I don’t remember exactly what it was, but I remember that the qt 5.9 and qt 5.13 libraries were in conflict