# Import error while importing cv2 in Spyder(Python 3.6)

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, spyder

I have already installed opencv 3.0.0 in windows os. I have run the application and have successfully installed it in `C:\` drive and have also copied the `cv2.pyd` file in `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages` as I saw in several tutorial videos and 
in my Python 2.7.5 Shell i.e IDLE when I type

> >>>import cv2
>
> >>>

It shows it has been safely installed and running.

Now I am using Spyder 3.6 as this is the latest version available for my Machine Learning programs but here if I follow the above steps it shows the error

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'

Now I copy the same `cv2.pyd` file in the path

`C:\Users\Chirantan\Documents\WinPython\python-3.6.5.amd64\Lib\site-packages`

But the error now is

> File "ipython-input-36-c8ec22b3e787", line 1, in
>
> import cv2
>
> ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

I have 2 questions do I have to install a separate opencv for Spyder 3.6 and install it in `C:\Users\Chirantan\Documents\WinPython`

and copy the `cv2.pyd` file in `C:\Users\Chirantan\Documents\WinPython\python-3.6.5.amd64\Lib\site-packages`

In this case it shows an error

> File "ipython-input-36-c8ec22b3e787 ", line 1, in
>
> import cv2
>
> ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

How do I solve this problem?

What should be the correct version of opencv to be installed for Spyder 3.6 and where should be the location where it should be saved and ehere should I put the `cv2.pyd` file?

Any Help Is Appreciated.

No I want to know what should be the correct version of opencv to be installed for Python 3.6 and provided I have an updated numpy that comes with the spyder package i.e winpython package, where should I install and save the correct file opencv in the winpython folder?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application. But the DLL's are there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19019720/importerror-dll-load-failed-1-is-not-a-valid-win32-application-but-the-dlls)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/

and copy `pip install opencv-python`

Now open `C:\Users\XYZ\...\WinPython` folder and open WinPython command prompt which is inside the folder `WinPython`

Here paste `pip install opencv-python` and press enter

Next type `pip install opencv-contrib-python` and press enter.

Voila! Your opencv is installed. Open your Python 3.6.5 Shell and type

> >>> import cv2
>
> >>>

It is successfully installed!

Answer (score 5):

Open Anaconda prompt then type the command

```
pip install opencv-python
```

and this worked fine for me for anaconda 3.

Comment: They're not using Anaconda

Answer (score 0):

It worked well for me. Answer is need to put `cv2.pyd` file to your virtual environment. Need to put under two folder of `envs`,

First is under `.dll` folder and second is under `Lib/site-packages`

To get `cv2.pyd`

Download from this link [enter link description here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/) and then extract the download file

You will get opencv folder, after that go inside opencv folder like

`Downloads\opencv\build\python\2.7` 
and go one hierarchy deeper in your folder structure depending on your your system architecture; *32- or 64- window version*

`Copy cv2.pyd` 
Important: **After copying `cv2.pyd` file to your `envs`, you need to rename `cv2.pyd` to _`cv2.pyd`**