# Getting DLL Load error while importing CV2 in Spyder (installed directly without Anaconda) - python 3.7

Tags: python, opencv, spyder

I have installed opencv on my system without any issues with following command:

`pip install opencv-python`

Installation was successful, but when tried importing open cv in Spyder it throws bellow error:

ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

I have referred this post on stack over flow: [DLL load failed error when importing cv2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43184887/dll-load-failed-error-when-importing-cv2) tried all the possible recommends mentioned, but no luck!

And when the same thing I tried on Command Prompt - python there isn't any error. Code works completely fine.

[image]

[image]

Comment: is spyder using the same python interpreter?

Comment: I googled a while, but, could you please help in finding the same ? @Belial

Comment: configure spyder with the same python interpreter as in cmd. And try this link.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51077327/import-error-while-importing-cv2-in-spyderpython-3-6

Comment: no idea how can I help remotely :) anyhow I would recommend upgrade python to the latest major version on both interpreters and then install opencv again.

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) If you want to use complex libraries like OpenCV, you should definitely try [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/download/) instead of using a regular Python installation. Please see [our video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ul79ihg41Rs) on how to uninstall your current Python and install Anaconda instead.