# Getting "OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application" error even after reinstalling the right version

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, path-variables, python-windows-bundle

I accidentally downloaded the 32-bit version of Python on my Win 10 (64bit). I uninstalled it, reinstalled the correct version, deleted all other python files/folders that I had, also reinstalled Anaconda, but I keep getting the same error when I try to do some stuff in Jupyter.

Is there a way to fix this? Am I missing a file that is still the 32 bit version which is why my PC keeps detecting and selecting the 32bit python version as well?

Comment: There is a similar question asked here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19019720/importerror-dll-load-failed-1-is-not-a-valid-win32-application-but-the-dlls

Comment: thanks but I havent found the answer in that thread for my problem.

Comment: Did you check the path variables? it should point to the new installation.

Comment: How do I check the path variables? When I google I only see how to set it up...

Comment: This link might help: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y2q_b4ugPWk as mentioned here, go to path variable settings and see if you have python path set there. If so, remove it and add the new installation path (assuming you have the admin access to your windows machine).

Comment: Also, remove any previous installation files from "C:\Users\<username>\AppData" folder

Comment: I have watched the video, but I dont see any python path there. I did remove a lot of python folders that were in AppData...since I dont see any python path anymore, can I assume I uninstalled all of python from my PC?

Comment: If no python path there,then probably you might not have set it. Please set the new path there. Once done, verify the python version installed by typing 'python' in cmd. If my comment helped, can you upvote it :)

Answer (score 1):

Alright, it seems I have indeed missed some files in AppData when removing the wrong python bit version. Removed all files, and installed Anaconda and 64bit Python again (making sure no old files were on my PC), and it finally works.