# I got an error while running import cv2.What is the soluton?

Tags: python, winapi, dll, opencv

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
    import cv2
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

What is the solution for this error?

Comment: Is this issue dumplicate [case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19019720/importerror-dll-load-failed-1-is-not-a-valid-win32-application-but-the-dlls)?

Answer (score 0):

Add the new opencv binaries path (C:\opencv\build\bin\Release) to the Windows PATH environment variable, restart python.