# WinError 193 %1 is not a valid Win32 application: when deploying Django on Apache

Tags: python, django, apache, wamp

I am on windows server 2012. I have built an API on Django rest-framework and I am trying to deploy it using WAMP and mod_wsgi. I have tested the API by running 'python manage.py runserver' and it's giving the expected output. The issue is when I am deploying it on WAMp using mod_wsgi
I am able to start WAMP service but when I try to reach 'localhost' it's giving me the following error:

[image]

below is the Traceback :

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8089/

Django Version: 3.0.5
Python Version: 3.7.6
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'rest_framework',
 'API']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Envs\predenv\Lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Envs\predenv\Lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 100, in _get_response
    resolver_match = resolver.resolve(request.path_info)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Envs\predenv\Lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 544, in resolve
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Envs\predenv\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Envs\predenv\Lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 588, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Envs\predenv\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Envs\predenv\Lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 581, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "c:\python376\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
    <source code not available>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
    <source code not available>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
    <source code not available>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
    <source code not available>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
    <source code not available>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
    <source code not available>
  File "C:/Users/Administrator/Envs/predenv/Predictor\Predictor\urls.py", line 18, in <module>
    from API import views
  File "C:/Users/Administrator/Envs/predenv/Predictor\API\views.py", line 2, in <module>
    from API.apps import ApiConfig
  File "C:/Users/Administrator/Envs/predenv/Predictor\API\apps.py", line 10, in <module>
    class ApiConfig(AppConfig):
  File "C:/Users/Administrator/Envs/predenv/Predictor\API\apps.py", line 13, in ApiConfig
    new_customer_model = pickle.load(new_customer_model_pkl)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Envs\predenv\Lib\site-packages\statsmodels\genmod\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from statsmodels.tools._testing import PytestTester
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Envs\predenv\Lib\site-packages\statsmodels\tools\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .tools import add_constant, categorical
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Envs\predenv\Lib\site-packages\statsmodels\tools\tools.py", line 4, in <module>
    import numpy as np
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Envs\predenv\Lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 140, in <module>
    from . import _distributor_init
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Envs\predenv\Lib\site-packages\numpy\_distributor_init.py", line 26, in <module>
    WinDLL(os.path.abspath(filename))
  File "c:\python376\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 364, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)

Exception Type: OSError at /
Exception Value: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application. But the DLL's are there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19019720/importerror-dll-load-failed-1-is-not-a-valid-win32-application-but-the-dlls)

Comment: @dirkgroten Ok, so it means one of the python package installed is of 32 bit as I am on 64 bit system? And is it 'statsmodels'?

Comment: No, it's `numpy`. I'm not sure about which is 32 bit and which 64 bit but yeah, basically your python doesn't match numpy.