# PyQT5 to PySide2, ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found

Tags: python-3.x, pyside2

I am trying to convert this PyQt5 example to PySide2.  I have modified a few other files and this is the first time I have encountered this problem.  The only difference between the two is using "PySide2" instead of "PyQt5" in the import statements, my code is shown bellow:

```
import sys
import qdarkstyle
import qtawesome as qta
from PySide2 import QtWidgets
from PySide2 import QtCore


app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
app.setStyleSheet(qdarkstyle.load_stylesheet_pyqt5())


def create_toolbutton(menu=False, popup_mode=None):
    toolbutton = QtWidgets.QToolButton()
    icon = qta.icon("mdi.pan", color="white")
    toolbutton.setIcon(icon)
    toolbutton.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(48, 48))
    if menu:
        toolbutton.setMenu(QtWidgets.QMenu())
        for i in range(3):
            toolbutton.menu().addAction("Action #{}".format(i))
    if popup_mode:
        toolbutton.setPopupMode(popup_mode)
    return toolbutton


toolbar = QtWidgets.QFrame()
layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(toolbar)
layout.setSpacing(10)
layout.setColumnStretch(0, 1)

labels = ["No Menu", "DelayedPopup", "InstantPopup", "MenuButtonPopup"]
props = [
    {"menu": False, "popup_mode": None},
    {"menu": True, "popup_mode": 0},
    {"menu": True, "popup_mode": 2},
    {"menu": True, "popup_mode": 1},
]
for i, (kargs, label) in enumerate(zip(props, labels)):
    layout.addWidget(QtWidgets.QLabel(label), 0, i + 1, QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
    layout.addWidget(create_toolbutton(**kargs), 1, i + 1, QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)

layout.setColumnStretch(layout.columnCount(), 1)

toolbar.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\Projects\Examples\Qt_examples\PySd2\popupbtns\popup.py", line 4, in <module>
    from PySide2 import QtWidgets
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

I am using Python 3.6.8  and pyside2  5.14.2.1

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application. But the DLL's are there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19019720/importerror-dll-load-failed-1-is-not-a-valid-win32-application-but-the-dlls) If it does, it was #1 on the search list for "python ImportError: DLL load failed".