# Error keeps on showing up when i try to install a module on python

Tags: python, pip

I am trying to install the modules shodan and requests but this error keeps showing up and i do not know why. It worked fine for my PC but when i tried it on my laptop this error keeps showing up.

I went to the scripts director of python and entered the following command:

```
python -m pip install shodan
```

and

```
python -m pip install requests
```

However, this error keeps showing up:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\TPBYOD\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "C:\Users\TPBYOD\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\TPBYOD\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip\__main__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from pip._internal import main as _main  # isort:skip # noqa
  File "C:\Users\TPBYOD\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    from pip._vendor.urllib3.exceptions import DependencyWarning
  File "C:\Users\TPBYOD\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .connectionpool import (
  File "C:\Users\TPBYOD\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 7, in <module>
    from socket import error as SocketError, timeout as SocketTimeout
  File "C:\Users\TPBYOD\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\socket.py", line 49, in <module>
    import _socket
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19019720/importerror-dll-load-failed-1-is-not-a-valid-win32-application-but-the-dlls

Comment: But from what i know, the python i installed is 64-bit

Answer (score 1):

i've resolved the issue already. Thank you. All i did was reinstall my python and ensured that python was added to both my current user's variable and my system variables

Answer (score 0):

This might be because your OS is 32 bit and the python version your using is 64 bit. Try installing 32 bit version of python and installing these libraries.

Comment: i've resolved the issue already. Thank you. All i did was reinstall my python and ensured that python was added to both my current user's variable and my system variables

Answer (score 0):

Try running the pip package manager directly:

```
pip install shodan
```

Comment: i've resolved the issue already. Thank you. All i did was reinstall my python and ensured that python was added to both my current user's variable and my system variables