# tensorflow show ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

hello guys this is debug log of my code idk why but this error is occurring to check if this error is due to cv2 i created a new python file and wrote 2 line code to check if error is due to cv2 but that code work fine . i dont know why this error is . pls help me solve this error im using pycharm. [image]

pls pls help to solve this problem as code is working fine. the code works fine on my old pc.

my new pc has **i5 9400f processor and gpu= gt 710 Nvidia python-3.6.0-amd64.exe** pls help soon

```
    "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/python online/Amita-master/Amita-master/workvidetest.py", line 5, in <module>
    import imutils
  File "E:\pyton p\amita new script\lib\site-packages\imutils\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .convenience import translate
  File "E:\pyton p\amita new script\lib\site-packages\imutils\convenience.py", line 15, in <module>
    from urllib.request import urlopen
  File "E:\python\3.6\lib\urllib\request.py", line 88, in <module>
    import http.client
  File "E:\python\3.6\lib\http\client.py", line 71, in <module>
    import email.parser
  File "E:\python\3.6\lib\email\parser.py", line 12, in <module>
    from email.feedparser import FeedParser, BytesFeedParser
  File "E:\python\3.6\lib\email\feedparser.py", line 27, in <module>
    from email._policybase import compat32
  File "E:\python\3.6\lib\email\_policybase.py", line 9, in <module>
    from email.utils import _has_surrogates
  File "E:\python\3.6\lib\email\utils.py", line 29, in <module>
    import socket
  File "E:\python\3.6\lib\socket.py", line 49, in <module>
    import _socket
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

Comment: Is your version of python 64 bit? How about the version of Windows? Is it 64-bit?

Comment: Lots of things here to try: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19019720/importerror-dll-load-failed-1-is-not-a-valid-win32-application-but-the-dlls

Comment: @WilliamD.Irons AS U suggested me to check which version i have so i have 64bit on 64bit os , i did python repair now pip is showing same error      import logging, socket, os, pickle, struct, time, re
  File "E:\python\3.6\lib\socket.py", line 49, in <module>
    import _socket
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

Comment: @WilliamD.Irons i already checked that bro , thank you bro

Answer (score 0):

the solution is to reinstsall the python64bit dont repair just reinstall and then make a new virtual environment in pycharm and install all the plugins you need