# Python error “import win32api” (searched answers but still)

Tags: python, winapi, dll, import

the script contains:

```
import win32api
```

When I run it, it gives me an error message “ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.”

I googled it and do accordingly whatever found including downloaded and installed from http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/, and also moved both files ‘**pywintypes27.dll**’ and ‘**pythoncom27.dll**’ to disk location c:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\win32. However the problem persists.

What can I do to have it working?

thanks.

Comment: *Which* answers have you searched? [This one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14629818/importerror-dll-load-failed-1-is-not-a-valid-win32-application)? [This one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19019720/importerror-dll-load-failed-1-is-not-a-valid-win32-application-but-the-dlls)?

Comment: did you install win32api using the setup.py file you downloaded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thansk *jonrsharpe* and *Vasili Syrakis* for the helps.

it's strange. I turned my computer off and on again. Found other modules involved scripts also return the same error message.

I uninstalled and re-installed Python 27 (Active Python). the problem disappeared...