# import understand (from sciTools) gives ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application

Tags: python, api, scitools

I'm trying to use the Understand api for Python.

```
import understand
```

I've already checked

- [ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14629818/importerror-dll-load-failed-1-is-not-a-valid-win32-application)

and

- [ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application. But the DLL's are there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19019720/importerror-dll-load-failed-1-is-not-a-valid-win32-application-but-the-dlls)

but they don't apply to my situation, as I already have the PYTHONPATH environment variable pointing to the correct location of understand.pyd, and also the url for unufficial python APIs does not contain the Understand api for python.

Any suggestion is much appreciated.

Comment: You've installed a 64 bit package for 32 bit Python.

Comment: Thank you Malik. By installing a 32-bit version for both, Python and SciTools Understand, the issue got resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've installed a 64 bit package for 32 bit Python.

Answer (score 1):

Installing a 32-bit version of Python and SciTools Understand, fixed the problem.