# Unable to load Iris dataset using sklearn

Tags: python, scipy, scikit-learn

I am trying to import IRIS data set in python 2.7 but getting series of errors. Can't figure out what exactly I am missing..

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
data = load_iris()
```

This gives me below error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/Python_Projects/Machine learning/Iris_data(improved).py", line 5, in <module>
    from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\datasets\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .base import load_diabetes
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\datasets\base.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ..utils import check_random_state
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from .class_weight import compute_class_weight, compute_sample_weight
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\class_weight.py", line 7, in <module>
    from ..utils.fixes import in1d
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\fixes.py", line 318, in <module>
    from scipy.sparse.linalg import lsqr as sparse_lsqr
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\__init__.py", line 109, in <module>
    from .isolve import *
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\isolve\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .iterative import *
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\isolve\iterative.py", line 7, in <module>
    from . import _iterative
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

P.S.:
I am using Python 2.7 (64 bit version),
scikit-learn (0.16.1),
scipy(0.15.1)

Comment: Probably, you installed 32-bit libraries on 64-bit Python.

Comment: Nope... I double checked and installed 64-bit lib

Comment: One problem could be the 32/64 bit thingy, which you say you ruled out. PATH problems could cause this too. See [answers here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14629818/importerror-dll-load-failed-1-is-not-a-valid-win32-application).

Comment: Are you using windows? I'd try to simply uninstall/reinstall, be extra critical about what to download

Comment: @AmiTavory Yes the culprit was the PATH... Thank you :)