# python, windows 7, can't import cv2

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, opencv

I know this subject has been brought up before, I've tried all the fixes I've found to no avail. When i try to import cv2 i get the message:

```
DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

I'm running `python 2.7` on `windows 7, 64bit`. I've tried installing `cv2` using:

```
python -m pip install cv2
```

as well as installing the `.whl` file (`opencv_python-2.4.12-cp27-none-win_amd64.whl`) the same way. Both times, cmd prompt tells me they've installed correctly, but I still can't import `cv2`.

The next thing i tried was downloading the latest version of opencv and following the directions [here](http://docs.opencv.org/master/d5/de5/tutorial_py_setup_in_windows.html#gsc.tab=0) to install it.

I also tried including the paths to the `.pyd` file in my environment variables:

`c:\opencv\build\python\2.7\x64; c:\Python27\Lib\site-packages`

I still get the error upon trying to import cv2:

```
DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

next, i tried the solved fix proposed in this thread next, I've tried the solved fix proposed in this thread [ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14629818/importerror-dll-load-failed-1-is-not-a-valid-win32-application)

However, i had no opencv binaries path that looked like (C:\opencv\build\bin\Release) so i added two paths, c:\opencv\build\x64\vc12\bin and c:\opency\build\vc11\bin to my PATH environment variables. However, this has no effect either and i still get the error upon trying to import cv2. what could i be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the wheel from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#opencv ?
There is a 2.4.13 available, maybe that will fix things?