# openCV DLL load failed: %1

Tags: python, opencv

```
>>> import cv2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 er ikke et gyldigt Win32-program.
>>>
```

I downloaded the newest version of openCV from https://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/opencv-win/

Then copied the `x64.pyd` from folder `C:\opencv\build\python\2.7` to `C:\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages` but it still complaints.

```
Python 3.5.1 |Anaconda 4.0.0 (64-bit)[MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
```

I saw an answer from another post here: [ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14629818/importerror-dll-load-failed-1-is-not-a-valid-win32-application) I found 2 dll files in my `C:\opencv\build\bin` and sat that path to my system variables. But did not result in success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Python OpenCV DLL must be made for your version of Python and your system architecture.

You could try each of these steps:

- Download OpenCV for your Python version (2/3)
- Try replacing the `x64` version with the `x86` version, AFAIK if you have installed the more common Python 32bit on a x64 system, you'll still need the x86/32bit version of OpenCV
- There are a lot of different binaries here: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#opencv. Try to get the one exactly matching your Python version and System architecture and install it via `pip` (**cp35** means **CPython** version **3.5** etc.).

  If you have the OpenCV `.whl` file matching your system configuration, do

  ```
  pip install file.whl
  ```

At least the last one should definitively work!

Comment: No problem, happy coding :)