# ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application (prime sieve import)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have 64-bit Windows 7 and 64-bit Python installed.

```
C:\Work\Python>python
Python 3.6.3 (v3.6.3:2c5fed8, Oct  3 2017, 18:11:49) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

I installed primesieve using this:

```
C:\Work\Python>pip install primesieve
Collecting primesieve
  Using cached primesieve-1.3.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl
Installing collected packages: primesieve
Successfully installed primesieve-1.3.0
```

I am then trying to run a Python program/script which is
importing this primesieve library but I am getting this error:

```
C:\Work\Python>run 500A

C:\Work\Python>python EulerProblem500A.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "EulerProblem500A.py", line 1, in <module>
    import primesieve # pip install primesieve
  File "C:\Programs\Python36\lib\site-packages\primesieve\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from primesieve._primesieve import *
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

I don't understand this error since the versions of OS, Python and primesieve library all match.

Any ideas?!

Comment: Do you have the correct version? This might happen if for example your python is 32 bit and the lib is 64, or reversed. I had a similar problem and I had to reinstall python using the 64bit version. Might not be the best solution, but worth a try (make sure you backup stuff you need).

Comment: @N.Ivanov Well, I specifically mentioned which bit versions I have.

Comment: That does not necessarily mean that you are using the correct ones. For example have you checked your python Path if it is pointing towards the correct version/directory?

Comment: @N.Ivanov I only have 1 python version installed which is 3.6.3 64-bit.

Comment: I guess, you have seen this update here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14629818/importerror-dll-load-failed-1-is-not-a-valid-win32-application

Comment: @Piinthesky No, I haven't. Thanks. What does it mean in my case? That I need to add the primesieve binaries to the WINDOWS path? If so, where can I find these binaries? I am new to Python. All I see is a pyd file here: C:\Programs\Python36\Lib\site-packages\primesieve

Comment: I wouldn't even pretend to have Windows knowledge. Apart from that - I know, you mentioned that you have Win 64 bit. But why does Python say in the first message `on win32`?

Comment: @Piinthesky I don't know. But the OS is 64-bit. I guess it is normal to see that message.

Answer (score -1):

Looking at the source code , you should import the following;

```
from libc.stdint cimport uint64_t, int64_t
from libcpp.vector cimport vector
cimport cpp_primesieve
```

*Seems like cython*

**Try**:

```
pip install cython
```

Also see https://github.com/hickford/primesieve-python

Comment: Import where? What do you mean "looks like cython"? I don't understand what you mean at all.

Comment: This application may need cython to run. Look at https://github.com/hickford/primesieve-python#development

Comment: Well, OK, I just installed the prerequisites `pip install cython pytest numpy` and still get the same error. Seems to me like that's not the problem.

Comment: Try install the appropriate c++ compiler from here https://wiki.python.org/moin/WindowsCompilers

Comment: Why do I need a compiler? What am I going to compile?

Comment: Do I need to compile anything? I downloaded/installed primesieve using pip.

Comment: primesieve in written in cython , not python