# pip install giving (ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application) error

Tags: python-3.x, pip

Was trying to upgrade python from 3.4 to 3.7. Uninstalled 3.4 and then installed 3.7. Now getting following errors while installing packages using pip.

```
C:\Users\Sia>pip install numpy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\sia\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "c:\users\sia\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\Sia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Scripts\pip.exe\__main__.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "c:\users\sia\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\__init__.py", line 20, in <module>
    from pip._vendor.urllib3.exceptions import DependencyWarning
  File "c:\users\sia\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .connectionpool import (
  File "c:\users\sia\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 7, in <module>
    from socket import error as SocketError, timeout as SocketTimeout
  File "c:\users\sia\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\socket.py", line 49, in <module>
    import _socket
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14629818/importerror-dll-load-failed-1-is-not-a-valid-win32-application)