# I cant install OpenCV to python. Following the instructions on OPENCV website but getting the following error:

Tags: python, opencv3.0

```
>> import cv2

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import cv2
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

[image: error]

Any suggestions would be gratefully received!

Answer (score 0):

A similar question has been asked before: [14629818](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14629818/importerror-dll-load-failed-1-is-not-a-valid-win32-application)

The solution they propose is that after installing OpenCV, you need to add the location of OpenCV to your PATH environmental variable and rerun your script.