# Paramiko: ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application

Tags: python, package, importerror

My python environment(2.7.11) had some issues, so I upgraded to 2.7.16 due to which few of the packages are creating problems. I understand Python 2.x is EOL, this is being used for Legacy Features Automation which doesn't need code maintenance and also have gone through few of the similar **DLL load failed** errors discussions and those all discuss about mismatch between 64bit and 32bit versions and environment variables,.. but my issue seems bit different from others.

[ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application. But the DLL's are there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19019720/importerror-dll-load-failed-1-is-not-a-valid-win32-application-but-the-dlls)

[ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14629818/importerror-dll-load-failed-1-is-not-a-valid-win32-application)

```
>>> import paramiko
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\paramiko\__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from paramiko.transport import SecurityOptions, Transport
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\paramiko\transport.py", line 91, in <module>
    from paramiko.kex_curve25519 import KexCurve25519
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\paramiko\kex_curve25519.py", line 5, in <module>
    from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import constant_time, serialization
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\constant_time.py", line 11, in <module>
    from cryptography.hazmat.bindings._constant_time import lib
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

Thanks in Advance for your responses.

Comment: Which version of paramiko are you using? And which version of Windows is this?

Comment: @C.Nivs Paramiko 2.7.1 version. Temporarily I have copied python from another System and continuing my work. If anyone knows the reason for this error, it will be of great significance .